# Scanning Java annotations at runtime

Tags: java, annotations, classloader

How do I search the whole classpath for an annotated class?

I'm doing a library and I want to allow the users to annotate their classes, so when the Web application starts I need to scan the whole classpath for certain annotation.

I'm thinking about something like the new functionality for Java EE 5 Web Services or EJB's. You annotate your class with `@WebService` or `@EJB` and the system finds these classes while loading so they are accessible remotely.

Answer (score 247, accepted):

Use [org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.html)

API

> A component provider that scans the classpath from a base package. It then applies exclude and include filters to the resulting classes to find candidates.

```
ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider scanner =
new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(<DO_YOU_WANT_TO_USE_DEFALT_FILTER>);

scanner.addIncludeFilter(new AnnotationTypeFilter(<TYPE_YOUR_ANNOTATION_HERE>.class));

for (BeanDefinition bd : scanner.findCandidateComponents(<TYPE_YOUR_BASE_PACKAGE_HERE>))
    System.out.println(bd.getBeanClassName());
```

Comment: Thanks for information. Do you also know how to scan classpath for classes whose fields have custom annotation?

Comment: @Javatar Use Java's reflection API. <YOUR_CLASS>.class.getFields() For each field, invoke getAnnotation(<YOUR_ANNOTATION>)

Comment: @ArthurRonaldFDGarcia, how can I scan `sub package` like that?

Comment: @CycDemo ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider includes sub-packages

Comment: NOTE: If you are doing this inside a Spring application, Spring will still evaluate and act based on `@Conditional` annotations. So if a class has its `@Conditional` value returning false, it won't be returned by `findCandidateComponents`, even if it matched the scanner's filter. This threw me today - I ended up using Jonathan's solution below instead.

Comment: How do you get the class? Do you have to use the classloader?

Comment: @Max Some example Class<String> string = String.class;

Comment: @ArthurRonald Sorry, Arthur. I mean that the `BeanDefinition` object does not provide a way to get the class directly. The closest thing seems to be `getBeanClassName` which returns a fully qualified class name, but the exact behavior of this method is not clear. Also, it's not clear which class loader the class was found in.

Comment: NOTE ALSO: this doesn´t work out-of-the-box for Interface classes, which one could need to scan for. Spring actively throws them out (calling the `isCandidateComponent(AnnotatedBeanDefinition beanDefinition)` method, which returnes a false for Interfaces) of the successfully scanned resultset. BUT you can change this behavior and also get back Interfaces - [just follow this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41504372/4964553). **If you use Spring Boot, than you should go with this solution first! The mentioned [fast-classpath-scanner](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25354394/4964553) doesnt work!**

Comment: @Max Try this: `Class<?> cl = Class.forName(beanDef.getBeanClassName());` http://farenda.com/spring/find-annotated-classes/

Comment: Most of these comments can be solved by using AnnotatedTypeScanner, which is a wrapper around ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.

Answer (score 159):

And another solution is [ronmamo's](https://github.com/ronmamo) [Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections).

Quick review:

- Spring solution is the way to go if you're using Spring. Otherwise it's a big dependency.
- Using ASM directly is a bit cumbersome.
- Using Java Assist directly is clunky too.
- Annovention is super lightweight and convenient. No maven integration yet.
- Reflections indexes everything and then is super fast.

Comment: `new Reflections("my.package").getTypesAnnotatedWith(MyAnnotation.class)`. c'est tout.

Comment: do I need to specify a package name? wildcard? what for all classes in classpath?

Comment: Beware that it still has no progress on Java 9 support: https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections/issues/186

Comment: the org.reflections library doesn't work right under java 13 (maybe earlier, too). The first time it gets called it seems to be ok. subsequent instantiations and uses fail saying the search urls aren't configured.

Comment: The link  Google reflections is invalid. It's a library that has nothing to do with Google.

Comment: @LluisMartinez I agree. I edited the answer accordingly

Answer (score 45):

You can find classes with any given annotation with [ClassGraph](https://github.com/classgraph/classgraph), as well as searching for other criteria of interest, e.g. classes that implement a given interface. (Disclaimer, I am the author of ClassGraph.) ClassGraph can build an abstract representation of the entire class graph (all classes, annotations, methods, method parameters, and fields) in memory, for all classes on the classpath, or for classes in whitelisted packages, and you can query that class graph however you want. ClassGraph supports [more classpath specification mechanisms and classloaders](https://github.com/classgraph/classgraph/wiki/Classpath-Specification-Mechanisms) than any other scanner, and also works seamlessly with the new JPMS module system, so if you base your code on ClassGraph, your code will be maximally portable. [See the API here.](https://github.com/classgraph/classgraph/wiki/ClassGraph-API)

Comment: Does this need Java 8 to run?

Comment: Yes, it requires Java8.  Uses streams.  I am going to see if I can modify it to use only v7.  I can't bear taking on another 700K of dependencies just to get this with `scannotations` or even more with `reflections`.  Sigh.

Comment: Updated to use Java7, no problem.  Just remove the annoations and convert the functions to use anonymous inner classes.  I like the 1 file style.  The code is nice an clean, so even though it doesn't support a few things I would like (class + annotation at same time) I think that would be pretty damn easy to add.  Great work!  If someone can't manage to do the work to modify for v7, they should probably go with `Reflections`.  Also, if you are using guava/etc and want to change out the collections, easy as pie.  Great comments inside too.

Comment: Right, the minimum requirement is now Java 7. The API has changed a little, see the github repo for details. (It's no longer a single source file, but I published the project on Maven Central, so it's still easy to add to a project.)

Comment: How can this be used in conjunction with spring context component scanning ?

Comment: I am using this approach in my project also. Thanks a lot. I have a question: is there a way to read the value of the class level custom annotation's value? Maybe I couldn't see it in your project

Comment: @PeterMel no, it is compiled in JDK 7 mode. It does not require JDK 8. Even the support for JPMS module scanning is entirely written using reflection, so as to be backwards compatible all the way back to JDK 7.

Comment: @Alexandros thanks, you should check out ClassGraph, it is significantly improved over FastClasspathScanner.

Comment: @AndrewBacker ClassGraph (the new version of FastClasspathScanner) has full support for Boolean operations, via filters or set operations. See code examples here: https://github.com/classgraph/classgraph/wiki/Code-examples

Comment: @Luke Hutchison Already using ClassGraph. Helped me with migration to Java 10. Really useful library.

Comment: @lamostreta reading annotation parameter values is now supported in ClassGraph. For class annotations, you need:
`scanResult.getClassInfo(className).getAnnotationInfo().getParameterValues()`

Answer (score 29):

If you want a really **light weight** (no dependencies, simple API, 15 kb jar file) and **very fast** solution, take a look at `annotation-detector` found at https://github.com/rmuller/infomas-asl

Disclaimer: I am the author.

Answer (score 20):

You can use Java Pluggable Annotation Processing API to write annotation processor which will be executed during the compilation process and will collect all annotated classes and build the index file for runtime use.

This is the fastest way possible to do annotated class discovery because you don't need to scan your classpath at runtime, which is usually very slow operation. Also this approach works with any classloader and not only with URLClassLoaders usually supported by runtime scanners.

The above mechanism is already implemented in [ClassIndex](https://github.com/atteo/classindex) library.

To use it annotate your custom annotation with [@IndexAnnotated](http://www.atteo.org/static/classindex/apidocs/org/atteo/evo/classindex/IndexAnnotated.html) meta-annotation. This will create at compile time an index file: META-INF/annotations/com/test/YourCustomAnnotation listing all annotated classes. You can acccess the index at runtime by executing:

```
ClassIndex.getAnnotated(com.test.YourCustomAnnotation.class)
```

Comment: It is not working in my case .I am doing run on server, java 11,Tomcat 9.0

Answer (score 16):

There's a wonderful comment by [zapp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1424321/zapp) that sinks in all those answers:

```
new Reflections("my.package").getTypesAnnotatedWith(MyAnnotation.class)
```

Answer (score 9):

Spring has something called a `AnnotatedTypeScanner` class. 
This class internally uses

```
ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider
```

This class has the code for actual scanning of the **classpath** resources. It does this by using the class metadata available at runtime.

One can simply extend this class or use the same class for scanning. Below is the constructor definition.

```
/**
     * Creates a new {@link AnnotatedTypeScanner} for the given annotation types.
     * 
     * @param considerInterfaces whether to consider interfaces as well.
     * @param annotationTypes the annotations to scan for.
     */
    public AnnotatedTypeScanner(boolean considerInterfaces, Class<? extends Annotation>... annotationTypes) {

        this.annotationTypess = Arrays.asList(annotationTypes);
        this.considerInterfaces = considerInterfaces;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Is it too late to answer. 
I would say, its better to go by Libraries like [ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.html) or like [Scannotations](http://scannotation.sourceforge.net/)

But even after somebody wants to try some hands on it with classLoader, I have written some on my own to print the annotations from classes in a package:

```
public class ElementScanner {

public void scanElements(){
    try {
    //Get the package name from configuration file
    String packageName = readConfig();

    //Load the classLoader which loads this class.
    ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();

    //Change the package structure to directory structure
    String packagePath  = packageName.replace('.', '/');
    URL urls = classLoader.getResource(packagePath);

    //Get all the class files in the specified URL Path.
    File folder = new File(urls.getPath());
    File[] classes = folder.listFiles();

    int size = classes.length;
    List<Class<?>> classList = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();

    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        int index = classes[i].getName().indexOf(".");
        String className = classes[i].getName().substring(0, index);
        String classNamePath = packageName+"."+className;
        Class<?> repoClass;
        repoClass = Class.forName(classNamePath);
        Annotation[] annotations = repoClass.getAnnotations();
        for(int j =0;j<annotations.length;j++){
            System.out.println("Annotation in class "+repoClass.getName()+ " is "+annotations[j].annotationType().getName());
        }
        classList.add(repoClass);
    }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Unmarshall the configuration file
 * @return
 */
public String readConfig(){
    try{
        URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("WEB-INF/config.xml");
        JAXBContext jContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(RepositoryConfig.class);
         Unmarshaller um =  jContext.createUnmarshaller();
         RepositoryConfig rc = (RepositoryConfig) um.unmarshal(new File(url.getFile()));
         return rc.getRepository().getPackageName();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return null;

}
}
```

And in config File, you put the package name and unmarshall it to a class .

Answer (score 2):

The Classloader API doesn't have an "enumerate" method, because class loading is an "on-demand" activity -- you usually have thousands of classes in your classpath, only a fraction of which will ever be needed (the rt.jar alone is 48MB nowadays!).

So, even if you *could* enumerate all classes, this would be very time- and memory-consuming.

The simple approach is to list the concerned classes in a setup file (xml or whatever suits your fancy); if you want to do this automatically, restrict yourself to one JAR or one class directory.

Answer (score 2):

With Spring you can also just write the following using AnnotationUtils class. i.e.:

```
Class<?> clazz = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotationDeclaringClass(Target.class, null);
```

For more details and all different methods check official docs: 
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/AnnotationUtils.html

Comment: Nice idea, but if you put a `null` value as the second parameter (which defines the class, in which inheritance hierarchy Spring will scan for a class which uses the Annotation), you´ll allway get a `null` back, according to the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for an alternative to [reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) I'd like to recommend [Panda Utilities - AnnotationsScanner](https://github.com/Panda-Programming-Language/Panda/wiki/Panda-Utilities:-AnnotationsScanner). It's a Guava-free (Guava has ~3MB, Panda Utilities has ~200kb) scanner based on the reflections library source code.

It's also dedicated for future-based searches. If you'd like to scan multiple times included sources or even provide an API, which allows someone scanning current classpath, `AnnotationsScannerProcess` caches all fetched `ClassFiles`, so it's really fast.

Simple example of `AnnotationsScanner` usage:

```
AnnotationsScanner scanner = AnnotationsScanner.createScanner()
        .includeSources(ExampleApplication.class)
        .build();

AnnotationsScannerProcess process = scanner.createWorker()
        .addDefaultProjectFilters("net.dzikoysk")
        .fetch();

Set<Class<?>> classes = process.createSelector()
        .selectTypesAnnotatedWith(AnnotationTest.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Google Reflection](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) if you want to discover interfaces as well.

Spring `ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider` is not discovering interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Google [Reflections](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/) seems to be much faster than Spring. Found this feature request that adresses this difference: http://www.opensaga.org/jira/browse/OS-738

This is a reason to use Reflections as startup time of my application is really important during development. Reflections seems also to be very easy to use for my use case (find all implementers of an interface).

Comment: If you look at the JIRA issue, there is comments there that they moved away from Reflections because of stability issues.

Comment: Reflections is amazing. However the use of it should be severely frowned upon because it makes code much harder to fix. For example, If your code reflectively looks for a method that you've somehow renamed using an IDE, the IDE probably wouldn't have modified the matching string used when doing reflection; and so it can hide bugs that could've easily been caught at compiletime and instead leaves them to silently crash during runtime. I still love Reflections though 