# How can I find all classes on the classpath that have a specific method annotation?

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I want to implement an intialization mechanism that is annotation-based in Java.  Specifically, I have an annotation I've defined:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Initialization {

/**
 * If the eager initialization flag is set to <code>true</code> then the
 * initialized class will be initialized the first time it is created.
 * Otherwise, it will be initialized the first time it is used.
 * 
 * @return <code>true</code> if the initialization method should be called
 *         eagerly
 */
boolean eager() default false;

}
```

Additionally, I have an interface:

```
public interface SomeKindOfBasicInterface {}
```

I want to find every implementation of the `SomeKindOfBasicInterface` class on my classpath that has the `@Initialization` annotation on a method.  I'm looking at Spring's `MetaDataReader` tools, which look like the best way to defer loading the other `SomeKindOfBasicInterface` implementations while I'm doing this... but I'm not sure how to do a search like I'm describing.  Any tips?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scanning Java annotations at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/259140/scanning-java-annotations-at-runtime)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use [Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections), which is a Java runtime metadata analysis tool. I've used it to get all subtypes of a given type, but it can handle your case as well.

Comment: I would strongly suggest to not use reflection or fundamentally the classloader, if time/space efficiencies are remotely of concern.  You may have a ton of classes in your classpath and all those loaded classes are now in permgen.  Use something like ASM (or a bytecode library) and simply read byte[]s, use the ASM library to get the info about the class e.g. 'is it annotated with x?' and then and only then actually load that class (if you happen to need that class).

Comment: @alphazero:  Reflection**s** does not actually use java.lang.reflect as such. It uses, similarly to the method you described, Javassist to read class metadata so as to avoid actually loading classes.

Comment: @Nicholas I would think that is JVM implementation specific. Haven't had a gander at the spec. (lately) so if that is indeed spec'd ("use javassist") would appreciate the link!

Comment: Note the link to Reflection**s**. It's a library, not the JVM built-in. See the link.

Answer (score 1):

I would basically create a [BeanPostProcessor](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html) implementation, maybe based on the [CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/context/annotation/CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html). Then I'd set up for [component-scan](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-scanning-autodetection) that scans the classpath and picks up all the beans matching your specification. When the bean is initialized, your postprocessor will be run.

I see I am assuming that you're looking for beans. If that's not the case you may have to scan the classpath yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [javassist](http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/) to find the annotations in your classes, even before you load them, but you need to read the .class files directly, which can mean opening a JAR by yourself, etc. Also you need to know where to look for the classes. You can't just ask the runtime for all subclasses of your `BasicInterface`.