# Get all of the Classes in the Classpath

Tags: java, reflection, class

How can I get list of all available classes in [`CLASSPATH`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) at runtime?
In Eclipse IDE, you can do this by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
Is there any method in Java to get it done?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can get all classpath roots by passing an empty `String` into [`ClassLoader#getResources()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResources(java.lang.String)).

```java
Enumeration<URL> roots = classLoader.getResources("");
```

You can construct a [`File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) based on [`URL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) as follows:

```java
File root = new File(url.getPath());
```

You can use [`File#listFiles()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles()) to get a list of all files in the given directory:

```java
for (File file : root.listFiles()) {
    // ...
}
```

You can use the standard [`java.io.File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) methods to check if it's a directory and/or to grab the filename.

```java
if (file.isDirectory()) {
    // Loop through its listFiles() recursively.
} else {
    String name = file.getName();
    // Check if it's a .class file or a .jar file and handle accordingly.
}
```

Depending on the sole functional requirement, I guess that the [Reflections library](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/) is much more exactly what you want.

Comment: What is meant by "classpath roots"? I noticed that `classLoader.getResources("")` only returns one or two directories on the classpath, those that seem to contain the .class files I wrote myself (and not those in 3rd party packages).

Comment: And if we wanted the complete list of classpath, shouldn't we use `URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader) classLoader).getURLs()`?

Answer (score 22):

Here's what I wrote to do it.  I'm sure it doesn't get everything if you're doing anything weird with the classpath, but it seems to work well for me.  Note that it doesn't actually load the classes, it just returns their names.  This is so that it won't load all classes into memory, and because some classes in my company's codebase were causing initialization errors if loaded at the wrong time...

```
public interface Visitor<T> {
    /**
     * @return {@code true} if the algorithm should visit more results,
     * {@code false} if it should terminate now.
     */
    public boolean visit(T t);
}

public class ClassFinder {
    public static void findClasses(Visitor<String> visitor) {
        String classpath = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
        String[] paths = classpath.split(System.getProperty("path.separator"));

        String javaHome = System.getProperty("java.home");
        File file = new File(javaHome + File.separator + "lib");
        if (file.exists()) {
            findClasses(file, file, true, visitor);
        }

        for (String path : paths) {
            file = new File(path);
            if (file.exists()) {
                findClasses(file, file, false, visitor);
            }
        }
    }

    private static boolean findClasses(File root, File file, boolean includeJars, Visitor<String> visitor) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            for (File child : file.listFiles()) {
                if (!findClasses(root, child, includeJars, visitor)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".jar") && includeJars) {
                JarFile jar = null;
                try {
                    jar = new JarFile(file);
                } catch (Exception ex) {

                }
                if (jar != null) {
                    Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = jar.entries();
                    while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
                        JarEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
                        String name = entry.getName();
                        int extIndex = name.lastIndexOf(".class");
                        if (extIndex > 0) {
                            if (!visitor.visit(name.substring(0, extIndex).replace("/", "."))) {
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".class")) {
                if (!visitor.visit(createClassName(root, file))) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    private static String createClassName(File root, File file) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        String fileName = file.getName();
        sb.append(fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf(".class")));
        file = file.getParentFile();
        while (file != null && !file.equals(root)) {
            sb.insert(0, '.').insert(0, file.getName());
            file = file.getParentFile();
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

To use it:

```
ClassFinder.findClasses(new Visitor<String>() {
    @Override
    public boolean visit(String clazz) {
        System.out.println(clazz)
        return true; // return false if you don't want to see any more classes
    }
});
```

Comment: You should use  String[] paths = classpath.split( System.getProperty("path.separator") );   otherwise  it wont work on Linux

Comment: I'd like to give this a try. Can you show the code to use ClassFinder?

Comment: This is bloody terrible.  Where's the implementation of Visitor interface?

Comment: @belgariontheking the code that calls `findClasses` should create an implementation (typically an anonymous class).  It's very similar to the callback you pass to `forEach` in JavaScript, for example.  I could have written the method to return an `Iterable`, but it would have been more complicated (if only Java had generator functions like a lot of other modern languages it would be simple to make it return an `Iterable`).

Comment: Wouldn't `File.separator` be better so the code is portable?

Answer (score 12):

You can make use of utility classes from the `com.google.common.reflect` package from the Guava library. E.g. to get all classes in a particular package:

```
    ClassLoader cl = getClass().getClassLoader();
    Set<ClassPath.ClassInfo> classesInPackage = ClassPath.from(cl).getTopLevelClassesRecursive("com.mycompany.mypackage");
```

This is concise however the same caveats as other answers describe, still apply, namely, that it will generally only find classes loaded by a 'standard' ClassLoader e.g. `URLClassLoader`.

Answer (score 1):

Every so-often I look for this.  It's kind of difficult because even if you manage to find everything on the classpath, you might not find everything available to a given class loader (for instance, I worked on a project that loaded class definitions directly from a DB once).

The best bet at this point is probably to look into Spring.  They scan the classes on the classpath to see if any have annotations that they need to kickstart stuff.

The accepted answer here is a good place to start:

[Scanning Java annotations at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259140/scanning-java-annotations-at-runtime)