# Static method in inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, static-methods

```
class A
{
    static{
        get();
    }
    static void get(){
        System.out.println("HELLO");
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

Output:

> HELLO

How is static method of class `A` getting called. I can understand static method of `B` getting called but not of `A`.

Comment: Static blocks are executed at class loading time similar question [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130461/when-is-the-static-block-of-a-class-executed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because B extends from A, if the B class is loaded, then the A class has to get loaded, and if it is loaded, its static initializer block must be called.

Comment: So if I write a static method in class B also then which one will be executed first ? A is instantiated first then B. ?

Comment: @Chaitanya - That depends on the reference being used. *static methods* cannot be overriden

Comment: And what if I wanted to call static method of derived class first.? Maybe its illogical question but is it possible.

Comment: @Chaitanya - First and second doesn't matter here. If you have a reference of derived class, you can call it at any time

Answer (score 1):

Because, since `B` is inheriting `A`, `B` has to load `A` when `main()` executes. This activates the `get()` function since it is in the static block.

Answer (score 1):

To execute the main method of class B, class B has to be loaded.

Class B extends class A, so to load B, class A must be loaded.

When class A is loaded, its static initializer is invoked, calling the get() method and printing "HELLO".

Answer (score 0):

In inheritance class loading is happens from top to bottom i.e. Parent to child.
It first loads the parent class in your case `A` and then loads the child class in your case `B`. And when class loads its static block get called first that why its printing `HELLO`

Answer (score 0):

During compilation the compiler knows that B is dependant on A. It passes the same data to the JVM. During *loading* phase of class B, the JVM reads metadata sent by the compiler and finds out that `B` is dependant on `A` and hence loads (and runs static initializers) of `A` then continues to load `B` and then initializes `B`.

If we had 2 classes `Sample` and `Test extends Sample` the Class Constant Pool (part of byte code ) for `Test` would have :

```
Constant pool:
   #1 = Class              #2             //  Test
   #2 = Utf8               Test
   #3 = Class              #4             //  Sample <---- reference
   #4 = Utf8               Sample
   #5 = Utf8               <init>
   #6 = Utf8               ()V
   #7 = Utf8               Code
   #8 = Methodref          #3.#9          //  Sample."<init>":()V   <-- init Sample
   #9 = NameAndType        #5:#6          //  "<init>":()V
  #10 = Utf8               LineNumberTable
  #11 = Utf8               LocalVariableTable
  #12 = Utf8               this
  #13 = Utf8               LTest;
  #14 = Utf8               main
  #15 = Utf8               ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
  #16 = Utf8               args
  #17 = Utf8               [Ljava/lang/String;
  #18 = Utf8               SourceFile
  #19 = Utf8               Sample.java
```

If you run java with `verbose:class` option then grep it, you will be able to see that the *dependant* class is being loaded.

```
java -verbose:class Test | grep 'Sample'

[Loaded Sample from file:/Users/XXXX/Workspaces/SampleTest/Sample/bin/] <== Sample loaded first because test depends on Sample.
[Loaded Test from file:/Users/XXXX/Workspaces/SampleTest/Sample/bin/]
```

Answer (score 0):

All Static blocks are executed at class loading time ... duplicate question [When is the static block of a class executed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130461/when-is-the-static-block-of-a-class-executed)