# Android - Static Block not being called first, why?

Tags: android, static, oncreate, static-block

From my Java understanding, static blocks should be executed before ANY other function.

I have a static block that calls a static function, both in class MyClass.java, that uses SharedPreferences object.

MyClass is used by MyApplication (Extends Application), somewhere in the onCreateMethod.

```
static {
    doSomethingStaticFirst();
}

private static void doSomethingStaticFirst() {

        //Log(DO_SOMETHING_STATIC_FIRST)

        UserPreferences userPreferences = new UserPreferences(MyApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext());
}
```

However I am seeing the following logs in order:

1. MyApplication onCreate method
2. DatabaseManager onUpdate (in case DB version increased)
3. DO_SOMETHING_STATIC_FIRST

Is there a particular reason why static blocks are not executed first? Will `MyApplication onCreate` method will be executed first over all?

Comment: In what class is the code you have shown? Is it in `MyApplication`? Is it in `DatabaseManager`? Is it somewhere else?

Comment: Somewhere else, in a class that is used by MyApplication

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When is the static block of a class executed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130461/when-is-the-static-block-of-a-class-executed)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your assumption is not accurate.

Static blocks in a class are executed when your class is **loaded** - which occurs the first time it is referenced in code.

If you really need to have your static block execute earlier, you can force-load the class - something like `Class.forName("com.foo.MyClassWithStaticFunctions")` earlier in the execution path will force the static blocks to execute sooner.