# How to remove Android ExceptionInitializeError?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, main-activity

I am getting the following error in my logcat:

```
03-28 15:07:12.758 27708-27708/in.aekansh.cortibae E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-28 15:07:12.758 27708-27708/in.aekansh.cortibae E/AndroidRuntime: Process: in.aekansh.cortibae, PID: 27708
03-28 15:07:12.758 27708-27708/in.aekansh.cortibae E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
03-28 15:07:12.758 27708-27708/in.aekansh.cortibae E/AndroidRuntime:     at in.aekansh.cortibae.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:130)
03-28 15:07:12.758 27708-27708/in.aekansh.cortibae E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
03-28 15:07:12.758 27708-27708/in.aekansh.cortibae E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
03-28 15:07:12.758 27708-27708/in.aekansh.cortibae E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2310)
03-28 15:07:12.758 27708-27708/in.aekansh.cortibae E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2419)
03-28 15:07:12.758 27708-27708/in.aekansh.cortibae E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154)
03-28 15:07:12.758 27708-27708/in.aekansh.cortibae E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
03-28 15:07:12.758 27708-27708/in.aekansh.cortibae E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-28 15:07:12.758 27708-27708/in.aekansh.cortibae E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
03-28 15:07:12.758 27708-27708/in.aekansh.cortibae E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
03-28 15:07:12.758 27708-27708/in.aekansh.cortibae E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-28 15:07:12.758 27708-27708/in.aekansh.cortibae E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
03-28 15:07:12.758 27708-27708/in.aekansh.cortibae E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
03-28 15:07:12.758 27708-27708/in.aekansh.cortibae E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
03-28 15:07:12.758 27708-27708/in.aekansh.cortibae E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources in.aekansh.cortibae.App.getResources()' on a null object reference
03-28 15:07:12.758 27708-27708/in.aekansh.cortibae E/AndroidRuntime:     at in.aekansh.cortibae.AndroidUtilities.<clinit>(AndroidUtilities.java:32)
03-28 15:07:12.758 27708-27708/in.aekansh.cortibae E/AndroidRuntime:     at in.aekansh.cortibae.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:130) 
03-28 15:07:12.758 27708-27708/in.aekansh.cortibae E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
03-28 15:07:12.758 27708-27708/in.aekansh.cortibae E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
03-28 15:07:12.758 27708-27708/in.aekansh.cortibae E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2310) 
03-28 15:07:12.758 27708-27708/in.aekansh.cortibae E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2419) 
03-28 15:07:12.758 27708-27708/in.aekansh.cortibae E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154) 
03-28 15:07:12.758 27708-27708/in.aekansh.cortibae E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321) 
03-28 15:07:12.758 27708-27708/in.aekansh.cortibae E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
03-28 15:07:12.758 27708-27708/in.aekansh.cortibae E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
03-28 15:07:12.758 27708-27708/in.aekansh.cortibae E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293) 
03-28 15:07:12.758 27708-27708/in.aekansh.cortibae E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
03-28 15:07:12.758 27708-27708/in.aekansh.cortibae E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
03-28 15:07:12.758 27708-27708/in.aekansh.cortibae E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904) 
03-28 15:07:12.758 27708-27708/in.aekansh.cortibae E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699) 
03-28 15:07:14.863 27708-27708/in.aekansh.cortibae I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 27708 SIG: 9
```

I don't know how to remove the error.

This is my MainActivity.java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    AndroidUtilities.statusBarHeight = getStatusBarHeight();

    chatMessages = new ArrayList<>();

    chatListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.chat_list_view);

    chatEditText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.chat_edit_text1);
    enterChatView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.enter_chat1);

    // Hide the emoji on click of edit text
    chatEditText1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (showingEmoji)
                hideEmojiPopup();
        }
    });


    emojiButton = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.emojiButton);

    emojiButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showEmojiPopup(!showingEmoji);
        }
    });

    listAdapter = new ChatListAdapter(chatMessages, this); //load the messages from the array.

    chatListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    chatEditText1.setOnKeyListener(keyListener);

    enterChatView1.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

    chatEditText1.addTextChangedListener(watcher1);

    sizeNotifierRelativeLayout = (SizeNotifierRelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.chat_layout);
    sizeNotifierRelativeLayout.delegate = this;

    NotificationCenter.getInstance().addObserver(this, NotificationCenter.emojiDidLoaded);
}
```

AndroidUtilities.java:

```
public class AndroidUtilities {

    public static float density = 1;
    public static int statusBarHeight = 0;
    public static Point displaySize = new Point();

    static {
        density = App.getInstance().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        checkDisplaySize();
    }

    public static int dp(float value) {
        return (int)Math.ceil(density * value);
    }

    public static void runOnUIThread(Runnable runnable) {
        runOnUIThread(runnable, 0);
    }

    public static void runOnUIThread(Runnable runnable, long delay) {
        if (delay == 0) {
            App.applicationHandler.post(runnable);
        } else {
            App.applicationHandler.postDelayed(runnable, delay);
        }
    }

    public native static void loadBitmap(String path, Bitmap bitmap, int scale, int width, int height, int stride);


    public static boolean copyFile(InputStream sourceFile, File destFile) throws IOException {
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destFile);
        byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
        int len;
        while ((len = sourceFile.read(buf)) > 0) {
            Thread.yield();
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        out.close();
        return true;
    }

    public static boolean copyFile(File sourceFile, File destFile) throws IOException {
        if(!destFile.exists()) {
            destFile.createNewFile();
        }
        FileChannel source = null;
        FileChannel destination = null;
        try {
            source = new FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel();
            destination = new FileOutputStream(destFile).getChannel();
            destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //FileLog.e("tmessages", e);
            return false;
        } finally {
            if(source != null) {
                source.close();
            }
            if(destination != null) {
                destination.close();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void checkDisplaySize() {
        try {
            WindowManager manager = (WindowManager) App.getInstance().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            if (manager != null) {
                Display display = manager.getDefaultDisplay();
                if (display != null) {
                    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 13) {
                        displaySize.set(display.getWidth(), display.getHeight());
                    } else {
                        display.getSize(displaySize);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    public static int getViewInset(View view) {
        if (view == null || Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
            return 0;
        }
        try {
            Field mAttachInfoField = View.class.getDeclaredField("mAttachInfo");
            mAttachInfoField.setAccessible(true);
            Object mAttachInfo = mAttachInfoField.get(view);
            if (mAttachInfo != null) {
                Field mStableInsetsField = mAttachInfo.getClass().getDeclaredField("mStableInsets");
                mStableInsetsField.setAccessible(true);
                Rect insets = (Rect)mStableInsetsField.get(mAttachInfo);
                return insets.bottom;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // FileLog.e("tmessages", e);
        }
        return 0;
    }



}
```

Please tell me where am I getting the NullPointerException. I think I have called all the necessary functions after `super.onCreate();` so I don't think there should be any problem. Please help me out. Ask me for more information if you need it.

******* UPDATE *******

App.java:

```
public class App extends Application {

    private static App Instance;
    public static volatile Handler applicationHandler = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Instance=this;

        applicationHandler = new Handler(getInstance().getMainLooper());

        NativeLoader.initNativeLibs(App.getInstance());

    }

    public static App getInstance()
    {
        return Instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like your App.getInstance() is returning null. Please post you App.Java code

Comment: Added. Hopefully this will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `App.getInstance()` is returning null. The issue here is static block code at AndroidUtilities.java:

```
static {
    density = App.getInstance().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    checkDisplaySize();
}
```

Static initialization blocks are run when the JVM (class loader - to be specific) loads StaticClass (which occurs the first time it is referenced in code) and before your application started (before `onCreate()` method of App class was invoked), you can read more at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420389/static-initialization-blocks) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130461/when-is-the-static-block-of-a-class-executed).

The solution is remove above static code block and create a static method at AndroidUtilities.java

```
public class AndroidUtilities {

    public static float density = 1;
    public static int statusBarHeight = 0;
    public static Point displaySize = new Point();

    public static void init() {
        density = App.getInstance().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        checkDisplaySize();
    }

    // your other code
}
```

App.java:

```
public class App extends Application {

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        Instance = this;
        AndroidUtilities.init();

        // your other code
    }
}
```

Comment: I did this:
    `private MainActivity Instance;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Instance = this;
        AndroidUtilities.init();
        //other code
       }
`
But I still get the same error.

Comment: Add at App.java, not MainActivity.java, and remove static code block

Comment: Well, my bad. Alright. I did that. Now `ExceptionInInitializerError` is gone but a new error has come up: 

`03-28 16:20:01.826 3864-3864/in.aekansh.cortibae E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-28 16:20:01.826 3864-3864/in.aekansh.cortibae E/AndroidRuntime: Process: in.aekansh.cortibae, PID: 3864
03-28 16:20:01.826 3864-3864/in.aekansh.cortibae E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object in.aekansh.cortibae.App.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
...`

Comment: Did you remove `checkDisplaySize()` from static block ?

Comment: I just did that.
Now I get this:
`FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: in.aekansh.cortibae, PID: 6134
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object in.aekansh.cortibae.App.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference`

Comment: In AndroidUtilities.java:
`public static void init() {
        density = App.getInstance().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        //checkDisplaySize();
    }`

Comment: Like this: static {
    //density = App.getInstance().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    //checkDisplaySize();
}, not at init()

Comment: Yes, I have removed that initial static block code. I replaced it with the one you told me to. And then, I went over to App.java and made the necessary changes. Then, this error still persists. Any idea what's happening?

Comment: checkDisplaySize() was invoked before onCreate(), you call it at somewhere else ? Is this all your code?

Comment: Remove all static block code that call App.getInstance()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107600/discussion-between-aekansh-dixit-and-tjeubaoit).

Answer (score 0):

Android Manifests check application, add android:name=".App" and android:allowBackup="true" and permission

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"></uses-permission>

 <application
        android:name=".App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
```

And activity add windowSoftInputMode attribute

```
  <activity
            android:name=".UserChatActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"></activity>
```

Grandle Control useLibrary and sourceSets.main

```
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    sourceSets.main {
        jniLibs.srcDir 'libs'
        jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
    }
```

Rebuid.