# Why does .class not invoke the static block in a Class?

Tags: java, class, static, initialization

This is the code I have:

```
public class StupidClass {
    static {
        System.out.println("Stupid class loaded!");
    }
}
```

And the tests I have, which I run **separately**.

```
import org.junit.Test;

public class StupidTest {
    @Test
    public void foo() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        final Class<?> stupidClass = Class.forName("StupidClass");
        System.out.println(stupidClass.getSimpleName());
    }

    @Test
    public void bar() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        final Class<StupidClass> stupidClassClass = StupidClass.class;
        System.out.println(stupidClassClass.getSimpleName());
    }
}
```

When I run test **foo** I will see:

```
Stupid class loaded!
StupidClass
```

But when I run the test **bar** all I see is:

```
StupidClass
```

Quoting from [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) page..

> Class objects are constructed automatically by the Java Virtual
>   Machine as classes are loaded and by calls to the defineClass method
>   in the class loader.

So my understanding is, in test bar, Stupid class is loaded, otherwise I would have seen a null I guess? So Class object is created because class itself is loaded..

And now quoting from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130461/when-is-the-static-block-of-a-class-executed) page

> Static initialization blocks are run when the JVM (class loader - to
>   be specific) loads StaticClass (which occurs the first time it is
>   referenced in code).

So I am expecting to see the "Stupid class loaded!" text in test bar as well, but I am not.

Also quoting from [Thinking in Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131872486)

> Each of the classes Candy, Gum, and Cookie has a static clause that is
>   executed as the class is loaded for the first time.

which is not very accurate it seems..

What am I missing?

Comment: You should mention if you run the two tests as one or separated processes.

Comment: @DuongNguyen I did? "And the tests I have, which I run separately."

Comment: My mistake. Interesting question. My guess is the class haven't really been loaded in this case.

Comment: @DuongNguyen - No. Its loaded. Its not initialized

Answer (score 61, accepted):

> Static initialization blocks are run when the JVM (class loader - to be specific) loads StaticClass (which occurs the first time it is referenced in code).

The above quote is plain wrong, but it is just one instance of a very widespread misconception.

1. Class *is not initialized* when it's being loaded, but when a static class *member* is first referenced. This is precisely governed by the [specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1).
2. Class loading *does not occur* when the class is first referenced, but at an implementation-dependent point.
3. The last moment when the class must be loaded is when the class is referenced, which is *not the same* as referencing a class *member*.

`Class.forName` initializes the class by default, but you have the choice of calling an overload that takes a `boolean initialize` and supplying `false`. You'll get the class loaded without initializing.

Comment: Note that it has to be a «`static`» member to trigger class initialization. Accessing an instance member implies either, a previous instantiation (so the class is already initialized) or an access to `null` which won’t trigger clazz initialization. This also implies that you can invoke `interface` methods without triggering the interface’s initialization.

Comment: I assumed that "class member" implied static member, but you're probably right.

Answer (score 24):

**Class Loading and initialization are 2 different things. A class can be loaded but not initialized until it is really necessary. Static initializers are run only when a class is being initialized <>  NOT loaded, "initialized"**

In the first case you are loading and initializing a class when you use `class.forName()`, that's why the static initializers are run and hence you see `"Stupid class loaded!"` as output . In the second case, you are just assigning a reference of the class, **the class is loaded** (use java -verbose:class to see what classes are loaded) but you aren't really initializing it (or to be more precise, not doing anything that forces the initializers to run). Thus you don't see the output as `Stupid class loaded!`. Try doing something like calling `newInstance()` on the class, it should force the  initialization of the class and you should see `Stupid class loaded!`

My code :

```
public class CheckPalindrome {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class<Test> t = Test.class;
    }

}
// class being loaded
class Test {
    static {
        System.out.println("aaa");
    }
}
```

**Classes that are loaded**

```
...
[Loaded Test from file:/Workspaces/SampleTest/Java8/bin/]
...
```

^ - This shows that the class is loaded but not initialized.

Comment: And I believe this is covered in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1 ,

Comment: @nos - It should be covered