# Execution of Java static blocks in subclasses

Tags: java, static, jvm, execution

I am preparing myself for Java certification test and I have found an interesting question related to the execution of Java static blocks. I have spent a lot of time reading about this topic, but I didn't find the answer I was looking for.

I know that static blocks are executed when the class is loaded into JVM or when the main method is invoked, but...

```
package oneClassTasks;

class Parent {
    static int age;
}

class Child extends Parent {
    static {
        age = 5;
        System.out.println("child's static block");
    }
}

public class XXX {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Child age is : "+ Child.age);
    }

}
```

The output is:

```
Child age is : 0
```

If I include verbose output with `-verbose:class`, then the output is:

```
...
[Loaded java.security.BasicPermissionCollection from C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded oneClassTasks.XXX from file:/D:/temp/bin/]
[Loaded sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper from C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Class$MethodArray from C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Void from C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded oneClassTasks.Parent from file:/D:/temp/bin/]
[Loaded oneClassTasks.Child from file:/D:/temp/bin/]
Child age is : 0
[Loaded java.lang.Shutdown from C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Shutdown$Lock from C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161\lib\rt.jar]
```

We can see here that **Child class is loaded** into JVM.

Can someone explain **why the static block from `Child` class is not executed**?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You saw that `Child` class was loaded, but it wasn't initialized.

Accessing `Child.age` doesn't cause the initialization of the `Child` class, since `age` is a member of `Parent` class. Therefore only `Parent` class is initialized, and `age` remains `0`.

> [12.4.1. When Initialization Occurs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4)
>
> A class or interface type T will be initialized immediately before the
>   first occurrence of any one of the following:
>
> - T is a class and an instance of T is created.
> - A static method declared by T is invoked.
> - A static field declared by T is assigned.
> - **A static field declared by T is used and the field is not a constant variable (§4.12.4)**.
> - T is a top level class (§7.6) and an assert statement (§14.10) lexically nested within T (§8.1.3) is executed.

In your case you accessed a static field declared by `Parent`, so only `Parent` is initialized.

Comment: Note that the last bullet about the `assert` statement doesn’t seem to match actual behavior in Java 6 to Java 9, I guess, that’s why it has been removed from the Java 9 specification.

Comment: Thank you. Everything makes sense now
P.S. I have to start reading more carefully. The explanation was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130461/when-is-the-static-block-of-a-class-executed) all the time. So, it has to be loaded and initialized

Answer (score 0):

In this case, Child.age is equivalent to Parent.age. JRE will treat it as Parent.age, that's why only Parent is statically initialized, and Child's static initializer is skipped.