# getClassPath() method in the WebLogic context class loader does not consider package preferences in weblogic.xml

Tags: process, jvm, fork, weblogic, classpath

1. A related problem: Get the **class path** from the context class loader (of **WebLogic** for instance)

This is already solved in [How to set up the context class loader's classpath for runtime compilation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23293534/how-to-set-up-the-context-class-loaders-classpath-for-runtime-compilation).

2. Current problem: Get **the same (proper) class path** used to run a web app

Reflectively calling the "getClassPath()" method works but it returns a **dirty** classpath containing unanted modules from **$ORACLE_HOME/oracle_common/modules** directory.

Problematic scenario:

1. Deploy a web app "Parent" in WebLogic // <- works
2. Get the context class path (it's a String object) by reflexively calling "getClassPath()" // <- works
3. Fork a process out of the main "Parent" process and run it using the context class path // <- fails

```
04:36:45,238 [Thread-41] ERROR ChildProcess - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapp
er.configOverride(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/MutableConfigOverride;
```

3. Explanation

While the context class path contains the necessary dependencies for the child process to run, they are overshadowed by WebLogic's own dependencies. The result is runtime failures such as the one shown above.

4. Workaround

a) Use a new version of WebLogic server that hopefully would use newer versions of the artifacts needed by the child process // risky endeavour
b) Manually process the context class path and remove any artifact that would shadow their more-recent counterparts

Solution b) looks more practical, but I don't like it for meany reasons:

- The reflexive call to "getClassPath" returns a String, and looking for artifact's names in Strings feels frail and weak
- I wouldn't know what shadows what. WebLogic **prepends** its weird artifacts at the start of the string before listing the web app's own dependencies.
- Only `weblogic.xml` has info on the web app's package preferences. I wish I could mimic how WebLogic processes this file to run the web app (Parent) and use that to properly run the child process

It seems to me that forking a process out from a web app running in WebLogic does not enjoy the same package preferences expressed in "weblogic.xml" that the web app (Parent) enjoyed when it was deployed and started running.

Other than the above suggestions, I am welcoming of any stronger solutions