# Java, get package name of class from string

Tags: java

all I have:

```
String desiredClass = "MyClass";
```

I want to instantize this class, but this name comes from this string. I know it can be done with:

```
Class.forName(desiredClass);
```

formula, but this also need the package path from this string (name.space.path.MyClass). I know it can be queried by `.getPackage()` - but again, it needs a direct class reference, not from a string. It looks a snake has bitten its end :)

Comment: It's not possible because you never have the information anywhere. If I ask you to give me the profile of 'Jeroen', I can't expect you to give me 'Jeroen Vannevel' because there are multiple Jeroens in the world. You'll require more specific information.

Comment: How do you obtain the `desiredClass` value?

Comment: @sp00m its in an XML setting.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel ohh, yes there is a point

Comment: you can't get the packaging only with the name.

Comment: You could use techniques listed in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222638/get-all-of-the-classes-in-the-classpath) to obtain a list of classes, which you could search for your class. But you'd need to be prepared for more than one matching result.

Comment: Can't you add the package as well in that XML setting?

Answer (score 1):

You need to know the package name before initializing the object.
Without it you wouldn't be able to distinct two classes with the same name from two separate packages.

If you had two classes `test1.MyClass` and `test2.MyClass` which one should be chosen in your code:

```
String desiredClass = "MyClass";
Class.forName(desiredClass);
```

So You need to know the package name in advance and do something like:

```
String desiredClass = "test1.myClass";
```