# Java standard library: Which methods are with biggest number of arguments in the library?

Tags: api, api-design, java, library-design

Which methods are with biggest number of arguments in the Java standard library?

Note: variable Arguments (Varargs) should be counted as 1 argument of type array instead of infinite number of arguments.

Reason: I'm trying to design better Libraries and I'm thinking of banning methods with more than 4 arguments maybe ...
So I'm trying to find methods in the standard library that have a large number of arguments and study the method and think of if it was needed to be defined like that and if there is a valid case to have more than 4 arguments.

Comment: I'm not sure what you'll learn from this exercise, and I'm certainly not going to scan the entire API, but off the top of my head there is the constructor for [`RSAPrivateCrtKeySpec`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/spec/RSAPrivateCrtKeySpec.html#RSAPrivateCrtKeySpec-java.math.BigInteger-java.math.BigInteger-java.math.BigInteger-java.math.BigInteger-java.math.BigInteger-java.math.BigInteger-java.math.BigInteger-java.math.BigInteger-) which has 8 args if I count correctly.

Comment: @JamesKPolk You don't have to scan it. The computer can do that for you ;-) I think the answer is "15 parameters for [`initMouseEvent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/events/MouseEvent.html#initMouseEvent-java.lang.String-boolean-boolean-org.w3c.dom.views.AbstractView-int-int-int-int-int-boolean-boolean-boolean-boolean-short-org.w3c.dom.events.EventTarget-)", as elaborated in my answer.

Comment: Of course I went ahead and scanned all the classes in Java 8 SE. And the winner is ... [`ImageReaderSpi`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/spi/ImageReaderSpi.html#ImageReaderSpi-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String:A-java.lang.String:A-java.lang.String:A-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class:A-java.lang.String:A-boolean-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String:A-java.lang.String:A-boolean-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String:A-java.lang.String:A-) with 18 arguments.

Comment: @Marco13: FYI, I only examined classes in [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/allclasses-noframe.html) list, and only public methods including constructors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The goal of limiting the number of parameters in own, public APIs is certainly a good one, but one should not blindly obey arbitrary rules and then apply quirky workarounds to follow them. Also, [other people's code](https://abstrusegoose.com/432) should sometimes only be an inspiration of how to *not* solve something...

---

That said, answering the actual question is a bit difficult. Do you want to...

- focus only on `public` or `protected` methods?
- only consider `public` classes?
- include methods in classes from things like JavaFX?
- include methods in classes that are `public`, but proprietary API?
- ...

---

However, I was curious. Using a [class to scan for all visible classes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19554704/3182664) (+1 there!), loading them (and blatantly ignoring errors), obtaining all methods from the valid classes and having a look at their parameter count, I could find some results:

- The overall winner seems to be from a class from the JavaFX runtime, called `com.sun.scenario.effect.impl.sw.sse.SSEPhongLighting_SPOTPeer`. The method is a `native` method that is simply called `filter`, and receives a whopping **37 parameters**: `private static native void com.sun.scenario.effect.impl.sw.sse.SSEPhongLighting_SPOTPeer.filter(int[],int,int,int,int,int,int[],float,float,float,float,int,int,int,float,float[],float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float,int[],float,float,float,float,int,int,int,float,float,float)`.

  However, the method is `private` and `native`, and the class cannot even be found in the OpenJDK JavaFX runtime repo, so I assume that it is auto-generated somehow.
- Limiting the whole search to `public` classes and methods that are also `public` or `protected` (and not `native`) still leads to one of the JavaFX classes. This time, it's in the `com.sun.prism.impl.VertexBuffer` class, which has a method called `addMappedPgram`, with **24 parameters**: `public final void com.sun.prism.impl.VertexBuffer.addMappedPgram(float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float)`, and the repo also contains [the source code of this method](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/9222246db895/modules/graphics/src/main/java/com/sun/prism/impl/VertexBuffer.java#l489).

  This is an example of a method where most coding guidelines would say that the number of parameters is far too high. But the parameters are so "regular" (following a naming pattern, probably related to 4 corners of a quad) that I think that something like this *can* still be reasonable. But the class is still not supposed to be used by clients, and has to be considered as "proprietary API".
- Omitting classes in packages that start with `"sun."` or `"com.sun."` brings us to what probably can be considered "the correct answer" to the question: The class `org.w3c.dom.events.MouseEvent` contains a method called `initMouseEvent`, which still receives **15 parameters**: `public abstract void org.w3c.dom.events.MouseEvent.initMouseEvent(java.lang.String,boolean,boolean,org.w3c.dom.views.AbstractView,int,int,int,int,int,boolean,boolean,boolean,boolean,short,org.w3c.dom.events.EventTarget)`. And here is [the JavaDoc API documentation of that method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/events/MouseEvent.html#initMouseEvent-java.lang.String-boolean-boolean-org.w3c.dom.views.AbstractView-int-int-int-int-int-boolean-boolean-boolean-boolean-short-org.w3c.dom.events.EventTarget-).

<sub>(A related side note: The function with the largest number of parameters that was supposed to be *used* by clients that I have encountered so far is a [function from cuDNN](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/cudnn-developer-guide/index.html#cudnnFindRNNBackwardDataAlgorithmEx) with **31 parameters**...)</sub>

## Update

In response to the comments, I now also covered *constructors*.

The class `javafx.scene.input.ScrollEvent` has two constructors with **23 parameters**, namely `public javafx.scene.input.ScrollEvent(javafx.event.EventType,double,double,double,double,boolean,boolean,boolean,boolean,boolean,boolean,double,double,double,double,double,double,javafx.scene.input.ScrollEvent$HorizontalTextScrollUnits,double,javafx.scene.input.ScrollEvent$VerticalTextScrollUnits,double,int,javafx.scene.input.PickResult)` and `public javafx.scene.input.ScrollEvent(java.lang.Object,javafx.event.EventTarget,javafx.event.EventType,double,double,double,double,boolean,boolean,boolean,boolean,boolean,boolean,double,double,double,double,javafx.scene.input.ScrollEvent$HorizontalTextScrollUnits,double,javafx.scene.input.ScrollEvent$VerticalTextScrollUnits,double,int,javafx.scene.input.PickResult)`. Here is the [link to the API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/ScrollEvent.html#ScrollEvent-java.lang.Object-javafx.event.EventTarget-javafx.event.EventType-double-double-double-double-boolean-boolean-boolean-boolean-boolean-boolean-double-double-double-double-javafx.scene.input.ScrollEvent.HorizontalTextScrollUnits-double-javafx.scene.input.ScrollEvent.VerticalTextScrollUnits-double-int-javafx.scene.input.PickResult-) for the latter.

---

The code that I used for my tests - this is ugly and hacky, but I think it should be added here:

<sup>(Edited to also cover constructors, in response to the comment:)</sup>

```
import java.io.File;
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Executable;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.jar.JarEntry;
import java.util.jar.JarFile;

public class ArgCounting
{
    static class Entry
    {
        Class<?> clazz;
        Executable executable;
        int numParams;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        List<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<Entry>();
        ClassFinder.findClasses(new Visitor<String>()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean visit(String clazz)
            {
                try
                {
                    System.out.println(clazz);
                    Class<?> c = Class.forName(clazz);
                    Method[] methods = c.getDeclaredMethods();
                    for (Method method : methods)
                    {
                        Entry entry = new Entry();
                        entry.clazz = c;
                        entry.executable = method;
                        entry.numParams = method.getParameterCount();
                        entries.add(entry);
                    }
                    Constructor<?>[] constructors = c.getDeclaredConstructors();
                    for (Constructor<?> constructor : constructors)
                    {
                        Entry entry = new Entry();
                        entry.clazz = c;
                        entry.executable = constructor;
                        entry.numParams = constructor.getParameterCount();
                        entries.add(entry);
                    }
                }
                catch (Throwable e)
                {
                    System.out.println("Ignoring: " + e);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        System.out.println("There are " + entries.size() + " executables");

        Predicate<Entry> executableIsNotNative = 
            e -> !Modifier.isNative(e.executable.getModifiers());
        Predicate<Entry> executableIsPublic = 
            e -> Modifier.isPublic(e.executable.getModifiers());
        Predicate<Entry> executableIsProtected = 
            e -> Modifier.isProtected(e.executable.getModifiers());
        Predicate<Entry> classIsPublic = 
            e -> Modifier.isPublic(e.clazz.getModifiers());

        List<String> skippedPackagePrefixes = Arrays.asList(
            "sun.", "com.sun.");
        Predicate<Entry> isSkipped = e -> 
        {
            for (String prefix : skippedPackagePrefixes) 
            {
                Package p = e.clazz.getPackage();
                if (p != null)
                {
                    if (p.getName().startsWith(prefix))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        };
        Predicate<Entry> isNotSkipped = isSkipped.negate();

        Predicate<Entry> executableIsRelevant = 
                executableIsNotNative.and(executableIsPublic.or(executableIsProtected));

        System.out.println("Methods:");
        printAllMax(entries, 
            classIsPublic.and(executableIsRelevant).and(isNotSkipped).and(e -> e.executable instanceof Method));

        System.out.println("Constructors:");
        printAllMax(entries, 
            classIsPublic.and(executableIsRelevant).and(isNotSkipped).and(e -> e.executable instanceof Constructor));
    }

    private static void printAllMax(Collection<Entry> entries, Predicate<Entry> filter)
    {
        int max = entries.stream()
                .filter(filter)
                .mapToInt(e -> e.numParams)
                .max()
                .getAsInt();

        System.out.println("Having " + max + " parameters:");
        entries.stream().filter(filter.and(e -> e.numParams == max)).forEach(e -> 
        {
            System.out.println(e.executable);
        });
    }

}

// From https://stackoverflow.com/a/19554704/3182664
interface Visitor<T>
{
    /**
     * @return {@code true} if the algorithm should visit more results,
     *         {@code false} if it should terminate now.
     */
    public boolean visit(T t);
}

// From https://stackoverflow.com/a/19554704/3182664
class ClassFinder
{
    public static void findClasses(Visitor<String> visitor)
    {
        String classpath = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
        String[] paths = classpath.split(System.getProperty("path.separator"));

        String javaHome = System.getProperty("java.home");
        File file = new File(javaHome + File.separator + "lib");
        if (file.exists())
        {
            findClasses(file, file, true, visitor);
        }

        for (String path : paths)
        {
            file = new File(path);
            if (file.exists())
            {
                findClasses(file, file, false, visitor);
            }
        }
    }

    private static boolean findClasses(File root, File file,
        boolean includeJars, Visitor<String> visitor)
    {
        if (file.isDirectory())
        {
            for (File child : file.listFiles())
            {
                if (!findClasses(root, child, includeJars, visitor))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".jar") && includeJars)
            {
                JarFile jar = null;
                try
                {
                    jar = new JarFile(file);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
                if (jar != null)
                {
                    Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = jar.entries();
                    while (entries.hasMoreElements())
                    {
                        JarEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
                        String name = entry.getName();
                        int extIndex = name.lastIndexOf(".class");
                        if (extIndex > 0)
                        {
                            if (!visitor.visit(
                                name.substring(0, extIndex).replace("/", ".")))
                            {
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".class"))
            {
                if (!visitor.visit(createClassName(root, file)))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    private static String createClassName(File root, File file)
    {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        String fileName = file.getName();
        sb.append(fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf(".class")));
        file = file.getParentFile();
        while (file != null && !file.equals(root))
        {
            sb.insert(0, '.').insert(0, file.getName());
            file = file.getParentFile();
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

(Note: The `ClassFinder` is from https://stackoverflow.com/a/19554704/3182664 !)

Comment: [`ImageReaderSpi`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/spi/ImageReaderSpi.html#ImageReaderSpi-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String:A-java.lang.String:A-java.lang.String:A-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class:A-java.lang.String:A-boolean-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String:A-java.lang.String:A-boolean-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String:A-java.lang.String:A-) has 18 arguments.

Comment: I think you skipped constructors.

Comment: @JamesKPolk The question asked for *methods*, but I have added constructors now. The winner here is one for [a JavaFX `ScrollEvent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/ScrollEvent.html#ScrollEvent-java.lang.Object-javafx.event.EventTarget-javafx.event.EventType-double-double-double-double-boolean-boolean-boolean-boolean-boolean-boolean-double-double-double-double-javafx.scene.input.ScrollEvent.HorizontalTextScrollUnits-double-javafx.scene.input.ScrollEvent.VerticalTextScrollUnits-double-int-javafx.scene.input.PickResult-) with **23 parameters**...

Comment: True, true. Personally I think of a constructor as a static method, but it's not really. However, for the goals of the question I think it qualifies.

Comment: @JamesKPolk The goal of the question is, admittedly, not really related to the reason of why I created this answer. Beyond that, one could argue about the bullet points that I mentioned, and consider adding `"javafx."` to the list of package prefixes to be excluded. In this case, `ImageReaderSpi` and `ImageWriterSpi` would indeed be the winners, with 18 parameters each for their constructors.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have an answer for the actual question asked but I do think I have some useful insight for the underlying question you're trying to answer.

I would refer to [Miller's Law](https://lawsofux.com/millers-law) here, which states that the average person can keep about 7 things in their head at once (note how local North American phone numbers are 7 digits).

This means, I would say that once you see around 7 of something, you should consider breaking things up and using composition.  For example:

- 7 classes per package
- 7 methods per interface
- 7 parameters for a function

etc.

After that, you can consider:

- Using multiple interfaces (especially if you can see a separation, or a chance to abide to the Interface Segregation Principle
- Create a subpackage or new top-level package for a subsection of classes in your package
- Utilize a Helper class, which could help absorb some arguments to your function
- In the case where you can't create a Helper, consider a Builder

This is flexible (for example, the law states it's really + or - 2) but I think it could serve as a useful baseline.