# Doing context:component-scan programatic way?

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I'm mixed using `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` and `ClasspathXmlApplicationContext` currently, and make `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` as the parent context. But I found that beans defined in `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` doesn't cope well with beans defined in `ClasspathXmlApplicationContext`. So I'd like to drop `ClasspathXmlApplicationContext` anyway, and make my application use `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` only.

The problem is, I don't know how to replace `<context:component-scan>` totally. I can easily do a package scan using `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.scan(...)`, but there seems no way to add include/exclude pattern in `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`.

Any idea?

Comment: Also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/259140/scanning-java-annotations-at-runtime

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't look like the class [AnnotationConfigApplicationContext](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/springframework/spring-context/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-context-3.0.5.RELEASE-sources.jar!/org/springframework/context/annotation/AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java?format=ok) provides exclusion/inclusion filters out-of-the-box. Internally the class uses an instance of [ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.html) to scan for annotations which provides the methods `addExcludeFilter` and `addIncludeFilter`. Unfortunately, the field is `private` and doesn't have a getter method so you can't just write an implementation that extends `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` and add include and exclude methods. Instead you'll probably have to copy the code from `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` and add the missing methods:

```
public void addExcludeFilter(TypeFilter excludeFilter) 
{
    this.scanner.addExcludeFilter(excludeFilter);
}

public void addIncludeFilter(TypeFilter includeFilter) 
{
    this.scanner.addIncludeFilter(includeFilter);
}
```