# Find loaded class with a specific annotation

Tags: java, annotations, classpath

I'm writing a custom, cross-platform serialization method which supports custom types (standard types being strings, numbers, maps, lists, etc.) by annotating a class like this:

```
@CompactTypeName("myapp.BetweenFilter")
public static class BetweenFilter implements NumericFilter {

    static {
        CompactSerializer.registerClass(BetweenFilter.class);
    }

    ...

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Deserialize
    private static BetweenFilter compactRead(DataInputStream ins) throws IOException {
        return new BetweenFilter(ins.readInt(), ins.readInt());
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Serialize
    private void compactWrite(DataOutputStream ous) throws IOException {
        ous.writeInt(from);
        ous.writeInt(to);
    }

}
```

The problem is that the static initializer there creates a runtime dependency on the serialization component, which the other parts don't (annotations not present at runtime are ignored).

To solve this, instead of the class registering itself with the `CompactSerializer`, the serializer should have some way of find the class and associating it with the given type name (*"myapp.BetweenFilter"*).

How can I do that? I know it's possible, since Spring-MVC, for example, can automatically find classes with `@Controller`.

Comment: This question may be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/259140/scanning-java-annotations-at-runtime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to scan the classpath. Basically: you'll have to

- find every classpath element (folder or Jar)
- traverse each element to find all items named *.class (by walking either the file system or the jar entries)
- load the classes
- check them for annotations (if you look for method annotations, scan all methods of all classes on your classpath)

Spring has highly specialized classes to do all of this. You *can* write this functionality from scratch, but it is a huge pain.

Comment: I'm using Google Reflections, from the link posted by Phill Sacre

Answer (score 2):

Look for more information about **annotation processors** in Java 6.