# Annotation Scanner in packages

Tags: java, jboss, annotations

I am looking for an easy way to look through a java package for my own annotation.

What I am trying to do is mark some classes with my own annotation. Every minute a scanner should scan some packages for this annotation.

With scanotation jar I tried that

```
URL url = ClasspathUrlFinder.findClassBase(FileWatcher.class);
```

and with AnnotationDB I could check if this class (FileWatcher.class) has the annotation. Now I need a list of classes in order to scan them all.

I read some articles and most people said it is not possible because of the classloader could load external jar files as well.

The other option I have is to copy all EJB Projects containing those annotations inside a subdirectory and scan all those jar files. I think that would might work, but is there no better way?

Many greetings,
Hauke

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [reflections](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/).  There are some [examples](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/source/browse/trunk/reflections/src/test/java/org/reflections/ReflectionsTest.java#70) in the test code.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. That helped a lot and it is working very easy. In case somebody needs that:

```
      String packagename = "de.whatever";

      final Reflections reflections = new Reflections(packagename);

      Set<Class<? extends CargoServiceListenerInterface>> subTypes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(CargoServiceListenerInterface.class);

      for (Class<? extends CargoServiceListenerInterface> class1 : subTypes) {
        System.out.println("Class : " + class1.getName());
      }
```

Instead of getSubtypes you can call also the annotation method.

If you use maven put this in the pom.xml

```
    <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>reflections-repo</id>
        <name>Reflections Maven2 Repository</name>
        <url>http://reflections.googlecode.com/svn/repo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
    <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a really **light weight** (no dependencies, simple API, 15 kb jar file) and **very fast** solution, take a look at annotation-detector found at https://github.com/rmuller/infomas-asl.
Scanning specific packages is very fast (matter of a few ms).

See also question [Scanning Java annotations at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259140) for other options

Disclaimer: I am the author.