# Scan the classpath for classes with custom annotation

Tags: java, guice

For example if I have annotation `@MyOwnAnnotation` and have these classes in my classpath, so that I could scan classpath possibly with some kind of filter (example. scan only packages starting with `my.own.app.*`)  and get list of all classes with annotation `@MyOwnAnnotation`? I'm using guice as injection framework and I don't use Spring.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, check out the [Scannotation](http://scannotation.sourceforge.net/) library.

Also, see the following blog post that [documents use of Scannotation](http://bill.burkecentral.com/2008/01/14/scanning-java-annotations-at-runtime/).

Basic example:

```
URL[] urls = ClasspathUrlFinder.findClassPaths(); // scan java.class.path
AnnotationDB db = new AnnotationDB();
db.scanArchives(urls);
Set<String> entityClasses =
    db.getAnnotationIndex().get(MyOwnAnnotation.class.getName());
```

Your annotations will need to have 'runtime' retention so that they are available in the `.class` file at runtime.

Comment: You may find other - better alternatives here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/259140/scanning-java-annotations-at-runtime or if you're not hang up on classpath scanning, see my answer below for alternate and faster solution.

Answer (score 3):

You could try my library [FastClasspathScanner](https://github.com/lukehutch/fast-classpath-scanner):

```
List<String> classNames = new FastClassPathScanner("my.own.app")
    .scan()
    .getNamesOfClassesWithAnnotation(MyOwnAnnotation.class);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd actually recommend another approach, better than all others (since they all use classpath scanning, which is slow). It's called ClassIndex and it INDEXES annotated classes:

https://github.com/atteo/classindex

Answer (score 1):

You can try corn-cps

Example:

```
List<Class<?>> classes = CPScanner.scanClasses(new PackageNameFilter("net.sf.corn.cps.*"),new ClassFilter().appendAnnotation(SampleAnnotation.class));
```

put the dependecy below in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.corn</groupId>
    <artifactId>corn-cps</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```