# guice return set of instances with custom annotation

Tags: configuration, dependency-injection, guice, dependency-management

I have very simple scenario where class A registers instances for types.

```
A.register(T1.class, new H1());
A.register(T2.class, new H2());
```

this is fairly simple configuration when done by hand but guice injection doesn't work when I create instances outside the guice framework.

I try to figure out how to create and configure A with all instance with custom annotation using guice.

I have found something like this [Scan the classpath for classes with custom annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317179/scan-the-classpath-for-classes-with-custom-annotation) but it is not using guice.

thanks

Comment: well I tried bindingListener but it is not an option too :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I guess code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Multibindings is the only option so far that works, but it is not as nice as I would expect since you need to connect everything by hand.