# ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents have wrong class name

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations

I have a java project containing a spring boot application called `processor`.  This project depends on a project called `rules` and a project called `service`.  Every project has the same package pattern - `my.com.package`.
The `processor` and `rules` projects both contain classes annotated with a custom annotation `@Condition`.  The annotation interface is annotated with `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)`.  When I scan for classes annotated with `@Condition` from `service` or `processor` like this

```
private ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider scanner = new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(
            false);
scanner.addIncludeFilter(new AnnotationTypeFilter(Condition.class));
        for (BeanDefinition bd : scanner.findCandidateComponents("my.com")) {
            try {
                Class<?> c = Class.forName(bd.getBeanClassName());
                Condition condition = c.getAnnotation(Condition.class);
                register(condition);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
                logger.error(e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }
```

The classes annotated with `@Condition` in the `processor` project have the correct class name(`my.com.package.x.Class`), but the classes annotated with `@Condition` in the `rules` project have an incorrect fully qualified class name(`my.com.Class`) and it only finds 2 out of 5 class names in the project that have the annotation.
If I change the argument to `scanner.findCandidateComponents` to the full package path in the `rules` project (`my.com.package.rules`) while scanning in either `processor` or `service` the scanner finds no candidates. If I use `my.com.*` as the argument it only finds the candidates in the `processor` project.
I saw a similar question here [Using ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider with multiple jar files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8807388/using-classpathscanningcandidatecomponentprovider-with-multiple-jar-files) and the solution was to pass the class loader to the component provider.  I tried getting the class loader of the class doing the scanning and passing it to the provider like this

```
scanner.setResourceLoader(new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver(classLoader));
```

and it didn't change any results for me.

Answer (score 0):

Silly mistake, the problem was I had the wrong version of the `rules` project defined in the pom for my `processor` project so it was using an older version of the code.
However this

```
Condition condition = c.getAnnotation(Condition.class);
```

returned null for the classes taken from the jar, so this concerns me a little if this code isn't being run from source in my workspace.