# Java how to check type of annotation when loading class

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

- I want to load class (which use run time annotation), and check the type of the annotation.
- The annotations are related to the fields.
- The class is not in the classpath and not in eclipse project

  - For this issue I needed to compile the class with it's annotation classes.
- I loaded the class using this link:

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0125__Reflection/URLclassloader.htm

After loading the class, I'm trying to get for each field it's annotations and check the annotation type:

```
Field[] fields = obj.getClass().getFields();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            Annotation[] ann = field.getAnnotations();
            for (Annotation annotation : ann) {
                if (annotation.equals(Example.class)) {
                    System.out.println("Example annotation");
                }
            }

        }
```

I expect to see the print "Example annotation" but I didnt get it.

The test.class and Example.class have the following java source code:

```
public class Test
{
    @Example (size = 5)
    public int x;

    @Example (size = 3)
    public int y;
}

public @interface Example
{

    int size();

}
```

The 2 classes where saved on different partition, and I compiled them with javac (and got 2 .class files)

I read:
1. [Java - loading annotated classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12021543/java-loading-annotated-classes)
But didnt get the solution.

So what Am I doing wrong ? (why cany I see "Example annotation") ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing an `Annotation` type to a `Class` type.

Try

```
Field[] fields = obj.getClass().getFields();
    for (Field field : fields) {
        Annotation[] ann = field.getAnnotations();
        for (Annotation annotation : ann) {
            if (annotation.class.equals(Example.class)) {
                System.out.println("Example annotation");
            }
        }

    }
```

Alternatively, you could use the [`instanceOf`](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0060__Operators/TheinstanceofKeyword.htm) operator:

```
if (annotation instanceOf package.Example) {
     System.out.println("Example annotation");
}
```

Note: Not tested locally, simply from reading.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 if (annotation.annotationType().equals(Example.class)) {
        System.out.println("Example annotation");
 }
```

**Update:**

The following test passes:

```
package annotation.test;

import org.junit.Test;

import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import junit.framework.Assert;

public class AnnotationTest {

    @Test
    public void TestAnnotationType() {
        Object obj = new ClassWithAnnotation();

        List<String> fieldList = new ArrayList<String>();

        // need to use declared fields as some are private
        Field[] fields = obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields(); 
        for (Field field : fields) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            System.out.println("processing field " + field);
            Annotation[] ann = field.getAnnotations();
            for (Annotation annotation : ann) {
                if (annotation.annotationType().equals(Example1.class)) {
                    System.out.println(field);
                    fieldList.add(field.getName());
                }
            }
        }

        Assert.assertTrue(fieldList.contains("string1"));
        Assert.assertTrue(fieldList.contains("string2"));
        Assert.assertFalse(fieldList.contains("string3"));
        Assert.assertFalse(fieldList.contains("string4"));
        Assert.assertFalse(fieldList.contains("string5"));
    }
}

class ClassWithAnnotation {

    @Example1
    private String string1;

    @Example1
    public String string2;

    @Example2
    private String string3;

    private String string4;
    private String string5;

}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface Example1 {

}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface Example2 {

}
```