# How to scan classes for annotations?

Tags: java, servlets, guice, guava

I have a plain jane servlets web application, and some of my classes have the following annotations:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(name = "/blog/")
public class TestController {
..

}
```

Now when my servlet applications starts up, I would like to get a list of all classes that have the @Controller annotation, and then get the value of the @RequestMapping annotation and insert it in a dictionary.

How can I do this?

I'm using Guice and Guava also, but not sure if that has any annotation related helpers.

Comment: Why are you trying to access the annotations directly? Are you planning on doing something with them? Are you just wanting a list of the classes with those annotations?

Comment: I'm going to get the value of the requestmapping and insert them into a dicionary.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scanning Java annotations at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/259140/scanning-java-annotations-at-runtime)

Answer (score 42):

You can use the [Reflections library](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) by giving it the package and Annotation you are looking for.

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("my.project.prefix");
Set<Class<?>> annotated = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Controller.class);

for (Class<?> controller : annotated) {
    RequestMapping request = controller.getAnnotation(RequestMapping.class);
    String mapping = request.name();
}
```

Of course placing all your servlets in the same package makes this a little easier. Also you might want to look for the classes that have the `RequestMapping` annotation instead, since that is the one you are looking to get a value from.

Comment: I can specify the package, that's not a problem or limitation.

Comment: Please note that this library is not maintained anymore (and has open bugs). I would not use it anymore

Comment: @Lonzak is there a library you would recommend using instead?

Comment: We replaced it with Spring. It is less code and well maintained. See the other answers given here e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63949320/2311528

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Spring,

It has something called a `AnnotatedTypeScanner` class. 
This class internally uses

```
ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider
```

This class has the code for actual scanning of the **classpath** resources. It does this by using the class metadata available at runtime.

One can simply extend this class or use the same class for scanning. Below is the constructor definition.

```
   /**
     * Creates a new {@link AnnotatedTypeScanner} for the given annotation types.
     * 
     * @param considerInterfaces whether to consider interfaces as well.
     * @param annotationTypes the annotations to scan for.
     */
    public AnnotatedTypeScanner(boolean considerInterfaces, Class<? extends Annotation>... annotationTypes) {

        this.annotationTypess = Arrays.asList(annotationTypes);
        this.considerInterfaces = considerInterfaces;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Scanning for annotations is very difficult. You actually have to process all classpath locations and try to find files that correspond to Java classes (*.class).

I strongly suggest to use a framework that provides such functionality. You could for example have a look at [Scannotation](http://scannotation.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Very difficult??? I'd say it's [very simple](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find) when you know you CLASSPATH (what you normally do). But I agree that using a good tool is a good idea.

Comment: It is very difficult if you want to do it efficiently. Especially if you don't want to create Class instances for all classes on the classpath.

Comment: Scannotation is EOL and not maintained since 2008.

Answer (score 2):

Try corn-cps

```
List<Class<?>> classes = CPScanner.scanClasses(new PackageNameFilter("net.sf.corn.cps.*"),new ClassFilter().appendAnnotation(Controller.class));
for(Class<?> clazz: classes){
   if(clazz.isAnnotationPresent(RequestMapping.class){
     //This is what you want
   }
}
```

Maven module dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.corn</groupId>
    <artifactId>corn-cps</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

visit the site https://sites.google.com/site/javacornproject/corn-cps for more information

Answer (score 2):

The following code worked for me, the below example uses Java 11 and spring ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider. The usage is to find all classes annotated with @XmlRootElement

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    var scanner = new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(false);
    scanner.addIncludeFilter(new AnnotationTypeFilter(XmlRootElement.class));

    //you can loop here, for multiple packages
    var beans = scanner.findCandidateComponents("com.example");
    for (var bean : beans) {
        var className = bean.getBeanClassName();
        Class clazz = Class.forName(className);
        //creates initial JAXBContext for later usage
        //JaxbContextMapper.get(clazz);
        System.out.println(clazz.getName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Instead of using reflection directly, you can make a lot easier for you by using AOP libraries from Google Guice. AOP is a common way for implementing cross-cutting concerns of an application, such as logging/tracing, transaction handling or permission checking.

You can read more about it here: https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AOP

Answer (score -4):

If you can get access of your .class files, then you may get the annotation using the class as below:

```
  RequestMapping reqMapping =  
                         TestController.class.getAnnotation(RequestMapping.class);
  String name = reqMapping.name(); //now name shoud have value as "/blog/"
```

Also please make sure, your classes are marked with `RetentionPolicy` as `RUNTIME`

```
  @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
```

Comment: The question was how to "get a list of all classes that have the @Controller annotation". Checking individual classes for the annotation is a completely different thing.