# Resolve dependencies with maven in java

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing

I am trying to make a mojo that takes all the unit tests from all the modules that have a certain annotation made by me. The problem is that I can't access the unit tests from any module.
The module structure looks like this:

```
|--ModuleA (depends on Module D)
|--ModuleB (depends on Module D)
|--ModuleC (depends on Module D)
|--ModuleD (the mojo)
```

The question is how to access or retrieve the unit test classes of each module when the mojo runs for it.

Comment: your test should be under /src/test/java. This module organisation is packaged already in jar ?

Comment: Yes, the test are under /src/test/java. And each module has its own tests and pom.xml. I am using the following example to retrieve the classes, but as I said, I can't access the classes from unit tests  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13128552/how-to-scan-classes-for-annotations

Comment: So you are trying to write a Maven plugin? Yes and what are those other modules for?

Comment: I am trying to write a Maven plugin for the project I am working on. The other modules are the main modules of the project that beside the usual classes it contains the unit tests for the classes, and that are the unit tests classes that I am trying to get

Comment: Why  the mojo must retrieve unit test classes? Unit tests verifies regular java code. When unit test pass, Roma locuta, cause finita, regular code is OK, unit test are not required anymore.

Comment: The mojo has to make an html with each test class and its methods from the entire project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Response since you told us about the dependencies of the modules.**
Best way to do this is : 
- moduleA, moduleB, moduleC built with maven
- generate test jars : add in your pom

```
 <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <executions>
       <execution>
          <id>test-jar</id>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
             <goal>test-jar</goal>
          </goals>
       </execution>
    </executions>
 </plugin>
```

- moduleD has dependcy on moduleA.jar,moduleB.jar,moduleC.jar & moduleA-test.jar,moduleB-test.jar,moduleC-test.jar
- add in your moduleE's pom.xml for each module :

  ```
    <dependency>
       <groupId>com.rizze</groupId>
       <artifactId>moduleA</artifactId>
       <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.rizze</groupId>
       <artifactId>moduleB</artifactId>
       <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.rizze</groupId>
       <artifactId>moduleC</artifactId>
       <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
  ```
- Module E is here to call all the test of Module A,B,C,D in the order you want to. Module E is making integration of all the modules in order to perform all the tests (as requested by you).

Comment: I can't add to moduleD those dependencies because it is creating a cyclic reference. The annotation is found in moduleD and the other modules have as dependency moduleD in order to add the annotation on the classes.

Comment: Than should add moduleE to global test

Comment: I am updating your questiion

Comment: Can you explain me what should I do with moduleE? I never used global test or found data that could help me