# Annotation scanning process in spring 3: rewriting in OSGI R4.3 spec

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee

I would like to port Spring annotations to The OSGI world and searching for some advices on this.

How are annotation scanned in Java-EE/Spring? I think it's by some weaving voodoo (aspectjweaver, asm?) or only by reflexion & classpath scanning.

Which Spring class is responsible of annotation resolution? Is it customizable?
Are there any other class that would require the weaving/classpath scanning feature (pre-post processing...)?

OSGI R4.3 specify a weaving spec in its world, do you think it will be a pain to adapt Spring with this? Any clue? I think it'll be far simpler than totally rewriting spring-dm modules but I maybe wrong...

The question can be used the same way with JSR-330 but I already know a project that will port it (pax-cdi).

Thank you in advance.

Charlie

Comment: Solvde for annotation scanning: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/259140/scanning-java-annotations-at-runtime

Comment: I think you should stop been lazy, and start to investigate spring in detail before try to port it to any other platform.

Comment: I just asked for advices

Comment: I strongly recommend not to start a question with a phrase that sounds in the readers ears like: I am to lazy to use Google, please provide me the links.

Comment: For sure. But this is not an information that we can find on google but on Github springframework sources... I'll edit the intro