# Component Scan for custom annotation on Interface

Tags: spring

I have a component scan configuration as this:

```
   @Configuration
   @ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {ITest.class},
                  includeFilters = {@ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = JdbiRepository.class)})
   public class MyConfig {

   }
```

Basically I would like to create scan interface which has `JdbiRepository` annotation

```
@JdbiRepository
public interface ITest {
  Integer deleteUserSession(String id);
}
```

And I would like to create proxy implementation of my interfaces. For this purpose I registered a custom `SmartInstantiationAwareBeanPostProcessor` which is basically creating necessary instances but the configuration above does not scan interfaces which has `JdbiRepository` annotation.

How can I scan interfaces by custom annotation?

Edit:

It seems that `org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider#isCandidateComponent` is accepting only concrete classes.

```
/**
 * Determine whether the given bean definition qualifies as candidate.
 * <p>The default implementation checks whether the class is concrete
 * (i.e. not abstract and not an interface). Can be overridden in subclasses.
 * @param beanDefinition the bean definition to check
 * @return whether the bean definition qualifies as a candidate component
 */
protected boolean isCandidateComponent(AnnotatedBeanDefinition beanDefinition) {
    return (beanDefinition.getMetadata().isConcrete() && beanDefinition.getMetadata().isIndependent());
}
```

Edit:

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Component
public @interface JdbiRepository {

   /**
    * The value may indicate a suggestion for a logical component name,
    * to be turned into a Spring bean in case of an autodetected component.
    * @return the suggested component name, if any
    */
   String value() default "";
}
```

Comment: How is defined your annotation ? I think you must have Spring's `@Component` annotation on `@JdbiRepository`

Comment: @GuillaumeDarmont it has Component annotation. But I guess that component scanning is working for just concrete classes.

Comment: Hmm. I did not pay attention to that. But since `isCandidateComponent` can be overriden, you may subclass `ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider`. But I don't know how to integrate it into Spring ApplicationContext loading (self registering ? explicit declaration ?...)

Comment: It will be my last option but before tomorrow I will try another approach as Spring Data project. They are registering components by interfaces. I will give a try, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said earlier, component scan is working only for concrete classes.

In order to solve my problem I have followed these steps:

1. Implemented a custom `org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar`
2. Created a custom annotation `EnableJdbiRepositories` which is importing my custom importer.
3. Extended ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider in order to scan interfaces too. My custom importer used this class to scan interfaces too.

Comment: You might have registered proxy implementation of `JdbiRepository` annotated interfaces as beans. Could you please guide how did you do it in your implementation of `ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar`. Could you please share some sample code?

Comment: This is a too old question but the answer here is https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11663 :) It will be resolved in M2.

Answer (score 6):

Creating a Dummy implementation seems quite hacky to me and all the steps [Cemo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/360594/cemo) mentioned require a lot of effort. But extending [ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/annotation/ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java) is the fastest way:

```
ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider scanningProvider = new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(false) {
    @Override
    protected boolean isCandidateComponent(AnnotatedBeanDefinition beanDefinition) {
        return true;
    }
};
```

Now you´re also able to scan for Interfaces with (custom) Annotations with Spring - **which also works in Spring Boot fat jar environments**, where the [fast-classpath-scanner](https://github.com/lukehutch/fast-classpath-scanner) (which is mentioned in [this so q&a](https://stackoverflow.com/q/259140/4964553)) could have some limitations.

Comment: Wait for spring 5.0 :) I had filed an isue and it was scheduled to be resolved in spring 5.0.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of scanning an annotated interface, you can create a dummy implementation and annotate it accordingly:

```
@JdbiRepository
public class DummyTest implements ITest {
  public Integer deleteUserSession(String id) {
    // nothing here, just being dummy
  }
}
```

Then, scan the dummy implementation `basePackageClasses = {DummyTest.class}`.

It's a bit of a workaround, but very simple and good enough for test purposes (as seems to be here).