# Java - Dynamically Adding URL Pattern to a Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-3.0

Is it possible to add a URL pattern to a Servlet dynamically at runtime?  For example, when the Servlet starts up, scan a folder for annotations, and then inject those url patterns into the servlet?

- to provide more clarity -

In the Servlet's init file, I want to do this (pseudo-code)

```
// scan all the files in the package my.project.services
// find all the classes with the Annotation @Service
// read those annotations, find the url patterns in them, and insert them into the servlet
```

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand. Do you want this at startup or later on?

Comment: At startup is OK.  In the servlet's init() function for example.

Comment: What's the purpose? Are you sure this wouldn't be better-served by using a simple controller pattern?

Comment: Maybe, but I'm trying to write a simple library for this project that will let me simply write new controllers, name their url patterns, and not edit the servlet or web.xml

Comment: Maybe you should use an existing library (spring-mvc or jersey for example)?

Comment: 1,2.Choose solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/259140/scanning-java-annotations-at-runtime. 3. Using generics get all fields by type of String, check on URL pattern. Do it in init of Servlet - profit! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your end goal, but here's a possible solution.

With Servlet 3.0, implement the [`ServletContainerInitializer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer.html) interface.  Register it as the javadoc says

> Implementations of this interface must be declared by a JAR file
>   resource located inside the `META-INF/services` directory and named for
>   the fully qualified class name of this interface

In its `onStartup(..)` method, you will have access to all the classes on your web application's  classpath.

Scan them one by one. If a class is in the package you want and it has the annotation you are looking for, process it and store the URL pattern in a collection.

When the scan is done, you can register `Servlet` instances/classes with the provided `ServletContext` and register URL patterns with the given `ServletRegistration.Dynamic` object.

```
ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration = servletContext.addServlet("myServlet", new MyServlet());
registration.addMapping(yourCollectionAsAStringArray);
```

You have many other configuration options as well if you need them.

Comment: @Koitoer Yes, I've added a clarification. Thanks.