# Fill annotation parameter value with value from properties file

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am developing a simple web app in Java EE. I use annotations for the servlets and I would like to fill the parameters of the annotation with value from a properties file but I don't know how to do this. I would like to do something like this :

```
// My Servlet    
@WebServlet(urlPatterns="${key.value1}")
    public class HomeServlet extends MyCustomServlet
    {
      ...
    }

# My properties files
key.value1=/home
```

Is it possible ? If yes, what is the solution ?

Thanks.

Comment: I want to set the value from the file because I want to put all the url patterns in the same file.

Answer (score 5):

That's not directly possible. The values you give to annotation attributes must be constants. They cannot be modified after the code is compiled. From the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.1)

> It is a compile-time error if the return type of a method declared in
>   an annotation type is not one of the following: a primitive type,
>   String, Class, any parameterized invocation of Class, an enum type
>   (§8.9), an annotation type, or an array type (§10) whose element type
>   is one of the preceding types.

However, if you controlled how they were processed (which I don't see how you would since these are processed by the Servlet container), you could get the value and do some placeholder resolution.

[Here's an alternative for dynamic url patterns.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21461797/java-dynamically-adding-url-pattern-to-a-servlet/21462193#21462193)