# Finding class by annotation - Java

Tags: java, annotations

I want to know if is possible to find class by annotation.
Example:

```
@MyAnnotation(string = "some string")
class Annotated class { some methods...}
```

so can I find this class in my package where I have many other classes with another annotations...

Just wonder if it's possible

Thanks

Comment: IMHO, you might be think backwards.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scanning Java annotations at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/259140/scanning-java-annotations-at-runtime)

Comment: at runtime or in your source code?

Comment: I believe that he means at runtime. There is no tag regarding IDEs

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Eclipse you can right-click the annotation, go to `References`, then pick the scope you want to search.