# Custom libraries that can detect the classes that import them

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am trying to find a way to get the name of the classes that import my custom library. Thus, if Class A imports libcustomA then libcustomA should know Class A's name at runtime. Thus, I can use the Class.forName(class A's name) to get a new instance of class A and do reflections on that class. I do not want to use a variable for Class A's name and have Class A provide me it's name. I want to do it more professionally than that like how spring and hibernate do it. Is there a way that I can ask the JVM for the class that is importing my library or something similar to that. 
Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scanning Java annotations at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/259140/scanning-java-annotations-at-runtime)

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot get the information of which class `imported` your `class`, you need to get a reference of the client class inside yours.
May be you can create an `interface` and ask the client `ClassA` to `implement` the interface and in your class from `libcustomA` have a method which takes the `interface`,and the `client` `ClassA` should invoked your method sending its reference `this`.