# Configuring base package scan for Spring Boot Application at Runtime

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I'm running a Spring Boot Application within a Tomcat instance packaged as a war file. I would like to be able to add "packages" to my instance in the form of rest services. To that end I need to be able to configure scanBasePackages in the @SpringBootApplication annotation at runtime. i.e. when tomcat starts up. For now I have ...

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages="path1, path2")
public class RestApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
   //code
}
```

...but I would like to have path2 be configurable and alternately be able to add path3, etc. if desired. How can I achieve this? I understand that I can't configure the String in the annotation so my question is about what other alternatives I have to this annotation for setting this.

Cheers.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259140/scanning-java-annotations-at-runtime

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try to use something like this in your project

```java
@Configuration
@Profile("custom-profile")    
@ImportResource( {"file:path/additional-context.xml" } )  
public class ConfigClass { }
```

and configure additional packages scanning in this file then.

```xml
<context:component-scan base-package="x.y.z.service, x.y.z.controller, x.y.z.dao" />
```

Note, your resource additional-context.xml declared as external and you have ability to change it without rebuilding war at all.

@ImportResource will be handled after declaring profile "custom-profile" as active. It's a safe way for starting application with "default configuration" without any "additional-context.xml" file of disk.

Comment: Ah cheers! But, for my case, it turns out to push the problem back a bit. For the "generic" install I want there to be no additional configuration file. If I make this be a file that doesn't exist or an empty string it complains that FileNotFound and the war fails to start. So the only thing I can think of is to have a dummy xml file that has nothing in it for the standard install. To do this maybe I need to use some sort of env variable so that my ImportResource value could be "classpath:${ENV_VAR}spring-context.xml". If ENV_VAR is not set it defaults to dummy spring-context.xml. thoughts?

Comment: @crowmagnumb you can declare your configuration as a part of a custom profile then, a import will not be doing on starting "default bundle" in this way. After activation required profile via standard Spring spring.profiles.active your custom configuration will be loaded without any problems.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"path1", "path2"})
```

Hope this helps :)