# Spring boot application won't run when trying to run from the jar file

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, jar

I have a spring boot application which works fine when run through intellij. But when I run it from the jar I am getting the below exception.

```
        2017-02-13 05:18:28.596  WARN 8581 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    2017-02-13 05:18:28.606 ERROR 8581 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

    org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:536) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.1.RELEASE]
        at com.testservice.challenge.testserviceServiceApplication.main(testserviceServiceApplication.java:13) [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [bus-route-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-exec.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [bus-route-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-exec.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [bus-route-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-exec.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [bus-route-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-exec.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:117) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:84) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:537) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:179) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:164) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.1.RELEASE]
        ... 16 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jersey.JerseyAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'applicationConfig.JerseyConfig' defined in URL [jar:file:/home/mayooran/Projects/bus-route-challenge/target/bus-route-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-exec.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/testservice/challenge/ApplicationConfig$JerseyConfig.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.testservice.challenge.ApplicationConfig$JerseyConfig]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.ResourceFinderException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/mayooran/Projects/bus-route-challenge/target/bus-route-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-exec.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes (No such file or directory)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:372) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:234) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:215) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:91) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:79) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:241) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.selfInitialize(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:228) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.access$000(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:89) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext$1.onStartup(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:213) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:55) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.1.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'applicationConfig.JerseyConfig' defined in URL [jar:file:/home/mayooran/Projects/bus-route-challenge/target/bus-route-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-exec.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/testservice/challenge/ApplicationConfig$JerseyConfig.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.testservice.challenge.ApplicationConfig$JerseyConfig]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.ResourceFinderException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/mayooran/Projects/bus-route-challenge/target/bus-route-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-exec.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes (No such file or directory)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1155) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        ... 35 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.testservice.challenge.ApplicationConfig$JerseyConfig]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.ResourceFinderException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/mayooran/Projects/bus-route-challenge/target/bus-route-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-exec.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes (No such file or directory)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:154) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1147) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        ... 47 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.ResourceFinderException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/mayooran/Projects/bus-route-challenge/target/bus-route-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-exec.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes (No such file or directory)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.JarZipSchemeResourceFinderFactory.create(JarZipSchemeResourceFinderFactory.java:89) ~[jersey-server-2.25.1.jar!/:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.JarZipSchemeResourceFinderFactory.create(JarZipSchemeResourceFinderFactory.java:65) ~[jersey-server-2.25.1.jar!/:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.PackageNamesScanner.addResourceFinder(PackageNamesScanner.java:282) ~[jersey-server-2.25.1.jar!/:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.PackageNamesScanner.init(PackageNamesScanner.java:198) ~[jersey-server-2.25.1.jar!/:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.PackageNamesScanner.<init>(PackageNamesScanner.java:154) ~[jersey-server-2.25.1.jar!/:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.PackageNamesScanner.<init>(PackageNamesScanner.java:110) ~[jersey-server-2.25.1.jar!/:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.packages(ResourceConfig.java:680) ~[jersey-server-2.25.1.jar!/:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.packages(ResourceConfig.java:660) ~[jersey-server-2.25.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.testservice.challenge.ApplicationConfig$JerseyConfig.<init>(ApplicationConfig.java:24) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        ... 49 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/mayooran/Projects/bus-route-challenge/target/bus-route-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-exec.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1045) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.JarZipSchemeResourceFinderFactory.getInputStream(JarZipSchemeResourceFinderFactory.java:177) ~[jersey-server-2.25.1.jar!/:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.JarZipSchemeResourceFinderFactory.create(JarZipSchemeResourceFinderFactory.java:87) ~[jersey-server-2.25.1.jar!/:na]
        ... 62 common frames omitted
```

Below is my pom file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.testservice.challenge</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>test-service</name>
    <description></description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-reflect</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-context</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                 <configuration>
                    <classifier>exec</classifier>
                    <mainClass>com.testservice.challenge.TestServiceApplication</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>springloaded</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2.6.RELEASE</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

I tried to create the jar by both

```
mvn clean package
```

and

```
mvn clean install spring-boot:repackage
```

Then I run the jar by java -jar -DParamName="someParam"

What am I doing wrong here? I am new to Spring. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have `spring-boot-starter-jersey` in your pom.xml. The error you are getting is `/BOOT-INF/classes (No such file or directory)`. This is the issue with jersey which doesn't work well with spring-boot fat jar. Please refer [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6598) and [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1468) for more details. For work around you have to package the classes that should be scanned by jersey in a jar and extract the jar as given at Spring-Boot documentation [Extract specific libraries when an executable jar runs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.x/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-extract-specific-libraries-when-an-executable-jar-runs)

Comment: How to package the classes that should be scanned by jersey in a jar? Can You give example?

Answer (score 6):

@abaghel answer has the correct explanation, and arguably the best solution as well.

Since Jersey's scanning step is what's failing, another way to work around it is to explicitly register each resource. I replaced this:

```
@Component
public JerseyConfig() extends ResourceConfig {
    packages("com.mydomain.resource");
}
```

with

```
@Component
public JerseyConfig() extends ResourceConfig {
    register(TimeResource.class);
    register(SpaceResource.class);
    // etc.
}
```

(Tested with Spring Boot 2.1.3)

My code has about 25 Jersey of these resource classes to register. This highlights the downside to this approach, namely that the explicit registration has to be maintained. New resource classes won't be found automatically, and it can be a confusing error to run into.

On the other hand, you don't need to split your project up. So explicit registration might occasionally be good enough.

Answer (score 4):

To add onto @Bampfer's answer since Googleing brought me here. This is a way to not have to unpack your resources in a separate module and have dynamic component scanning.

Create an custom annotation `@JaxRsResource` that you put on any resource class.

```java
public @interface JaxRsResource {
}
```

```java
@Named
@JaxRsResource
@Path("/my/api/path")
public class MyResource {
    @GET
    public String helloWorld() { return "Hello World"; }
}
```

I then utilized spring's component scanning api from this post: [Scanning Java annotations at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259140/scanning-java-annotations-at-runtime) and registered the components I found with my custom annotation and called the register function.

```java
@Configuration
public class JaxrsApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JaxrsApplication.class);

    public JaxrsApplication() {

        final ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider scanner =
                new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(false);

        scanner.addIncludeFilter(new AnnotationTypeFilter(JaxRsResource.class));

        for (final BeanDefinition resourceBean : scanner.findCandidateComponents("my.base.package")) {
                try {
                    final Class resourceClass = getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass(resourceBean.getBeanClassName());
                    register(resourceClass);
                } catch (final ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    logger.error(String.format("Unable to load Jax-RS resource {}.", resourceBean.getBeanClassName()), e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: You have to load the class from the class loader and pass the Class object to register(). If you only pass the class name as a string to the register method it won't load the resource.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this by replaceing:

```
public class JerseyResourceConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public JerseyResourceConfig() {
        packages("com.mydomain.resource");
    }
}
```

with

```
public class JerseyResourceConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public JerseyResourceConfig(@Context ServletContext context) {
        WebApplicationContext appCtx = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(context);
        registerInstances(new HashSet(appCtx.getBeansWithAnnotation(Path.class).values()));
    }
}
```

Comment: When I tried this I got `Could not autowire: No beans of of 'ServletContext' type found`