# Spring boot app with Netfilx Eureka fails to start after being packaged into a fat jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jar, netflix-eureka

So I have been following this [Microservices with Spring Boot](https://medium.com/omarelgabrys-blog/microservices-with-spring-boot-creating-our-microserivces-gateway-part-2-31f8aa6b215b) guide and everything seems to work as expected in the IDE(intelliJ IDEA), the Eureka Server starts and functions as expected. 
However, a problem occured after I exported my Eureka server as a fat jar.

To package the Eureka server into a fat jar I used `mvn clean package` in the terminal which has always worked for me.

After that when I tried to run the jar using `java -jar myjar.jar` I got the following exception

```
    org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:155) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.tushinov.ServiceRegistryStarter.main(ServiceRegistryStarter.java:11) [classes!/:1.0]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [service-registry-1.0.jar:1.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [service-registry-1.0.jar:1.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [service-registry-1.0.jar:1.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [service-registry-1.0.jar:1.0]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:125) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:417) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:176) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:179) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:152) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[] failed to start
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.rethrowDeferredStartupExceptions(TomcatWebServer.java:171) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:110) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        ... 21 common frames omitted
```

After looking around in Stackoverflow I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42194680/spring-boot-application-wont-run-when-trying-to-run-from-the-jar-file) question but it did not manage to help me with the problem. So I decided to ask a question myself.

I have used `mvn clean package` for making fat jars for quite some time and never had an issue. How come this time it fails? Im guessing it has something to do with the netflix eureka server. Maybe a missing configuration or something similar.

So here is everything that I currently have:

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.tushinov</groupId>
    <artifactId>service-registry</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.properties

```
spring.application.name=eureka-server

server.port=8761

eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
```

and the code

```
package org.tushinov;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class ServiceRegistryStarter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServiceRegistryStarter.class, args);
    }
}
```

If I have missed anything please ask away in the comments for clarification.
Any help and/or suggestion are welcome and greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time I found the answer to this problem. It was not a configuration or anything like it. It was a JDK mistmatch in intelliJ and maven. In intelliJ I was using JDK 1.8 to compile and run my application.

The thing I did not realise was that `mvn` uses the `JAVA_HOME` parameter to find which JDK it is supposed to use as opposed to intelliJ where you can specify your jdk. The `JAVA_HOME` parameter in my case was pointing to JDK 1.9, which, apperantly, might need more dependencies and/or configuration in order to run the Netflix Eureka server.

These [resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654557/how-to-set-specific-java-version-to-maven) helped me with solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is pom which works for me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example.microservices</groupId>
    <artifactId>naming-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>naming-server</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.M9</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```