# Is there any Spring Boot with Jersey framework that supports OpenAPI 3.0?

Tags: spring-boot, jersey, swagger, cxf, openapi

There are a ton of tutorials regarding Spring Boot, JAX-RS, and Swagger. However, most of them seem to use the OpenAPI 2 specification. I only found one tutorial that uses Spring, JAX-RS, and OpenAPI 3.0 (that tutorial used Apache CXF).

https://dzone.com/articles/moving-with-the-times-towards-openapi-v300-adoptio

Do any other Spring Boot + JAX-RS implementations work with OpenAPI 3.0? For example, all tutorials with Jersey only seem to output OpenAPI 2.0. Apache CXF is fine for what I'm doing but I would like to know if there are options.

Springdoc-openapi supports spring boot and OpenAPI 3.0, unsure about jaxrs. 
https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi

Comment: did you find any interesting thing since you posted you question here ?

Answer (score 10):

### Configuration of Spring Boot with JAX-RS producing OpenAPI 3.0 specification

You can use *Swagger* to generate an *OpenAPI 3.0* together with *Spring Boot* and *JAX-RS* by doing the following:

1. Include `spring-boot-starter-jersey`, `swagger-core`, `swagger-annotations` and `swagger-jaxrs` in `pom.xml`
2. Extend `ResourceConfig` and configure the packages to scan for *JAX-RS* annotations and register the `OpenAPIResource.class` of *Swagger*.
3. Use Swagger Annotations to annotate your endpoints and your schema.
4. Optionally include `sprindoc-openapi-ui` if you want to access *Swagger* via `/swagger-ui.html`.

**1) Dependencies in pom.xml**

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${swagger.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-core</artifactId>
        <version>${swagger.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs2</artifactId>
        <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>io.github.classgraph</groupId>
                <artifactId>classgraph</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.18</version>
    </dependency>
```

Current `swagger-version` is `2.1.0`.

There is a conflict with `springdoc-openapi-ui` and `swagger-jaxrs2`, which leads to an error with `io.github.classgraph` so this library must be excluded from `swagger-jaxrs2`.

**2: Extending ResourceConfig**

```java
@Component
@ApplicationPath("/api")
@Path("/")
public class JaxRsConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public JaxRsConfig() {
        // register resources
        packages("com.example.jaxrs.resources");
        register(OpenApiResource.class);
    }
}
```

The *JAX-RS* annotated resources must be scanned by calling `packages("com.example.jaxrs.resources")`.

**Be careful, not to confuse with the** `register` **function!**

The `OpenApiResource.class` comes from *Swagger* and offers the `/openapi.json` endpoint.

The reason why I use `/api` as `@ApplicationPath` is, that when using it together with `springdoc-openapi-ui`, the `swagger-ui.html` endpoint is not found when the `@ApplicationPath` is set to "/". It seems that something is getting overwritten in this case. Maybe someone has an explanation for this.

**3) Swagger Annotations**

```java
@Schema(name = "Message", description = "This is an object to place a message.")
public class MessageDto {

    @Schema(name="Message", required = true)
    private String message;

    public MessageDto(String message) {
        super();
        this.message = message;
    }
    // ... getters and setters
}
```

**4) Configuring SpringDoc**

By default, you should be able to call `/swagger-ui.html` to open *Swagger* and browse your *OpenAPI 3.0* definition.

Since the `@ApplicationPath` is set to `/api`, we need to configure *SpringDoc* where to look for the definition by setting a property in `application.properties`:

> springdoc.api-docs.path=/api/openapi.json

You can also change the URL of *Swagger* with:

> springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/swagger-ui.html

**Other issues:**

Another issue may arise, when running the application as a `.jar` file:

[Spring boot application won't run when trying to run from the jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42194680/spring-boot-application-wont-run-when-trying-to-run-from-the-jar-file)

In this case I've found a solution by scanning all the components with a reflection library like `org.reflections` like so:

```java
    private void scan(String... packages) {
        for (String packageName : packages) {
            Reflections reflections = new Reflections(packageName);
            reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Provider.class).parallelStream().forEach(clazz -> register(clazz));
            reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Path.class).parallelStream().forEach(clazz -> register(clazz));
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is a great help.
Question: when I try to load the swagger-ui.html, it redirected to /swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=/api/openapi.json/swagger-config

However, there's nothing for swagger-config.
Am I missing any configuration?

Comment: @Vijay I would love to know if you have solved that

Comment: As per the Spring documentation, it doesn't support Jersey APIs.

Answer (score 1):

Adding an answer because I can't comment or edit.

> Question: when I try to load the swagger-ui.html, it redirected to /swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=/api/openapi.json/swagger-config However, there's nothing for swagger-config. Am I missing any configuration?

I had that problem as well. I was able to fix it by adding the following property to my `application.properties`:

> springdoc.swagger-ui.display-query-params=true

The problem is weird and somehow the solution is even weirder. But hey, it works!

Answer (score 1):

Since 1.6, isDisplayQueryParams() has been removed from SwaggerUiConfigProperties but this solution works :

```
springdoc.swagger-ui.url=/api/openapi.json
```

Principle :

```
1) GET /swagger-ui/index.html
2) GET /v3/api-docs/swagger-config
    [Response body]
    configUrl: "/v3/api-docs/swagger-config"
    oauth2RedirectUrl: "(...)"
    operationsSorter: "method"
    url: "/api/openapi.json" // <=> springdoc.swagger-ui.url
    validatorUrl: ""
3) GET /api/openapi.json
```