# How to get Class<?>classList annotated with @Entity under com.packageA.domain and com.packageB.domain?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I have a method

```
public RepositoryRestConfiguration exposeIdsFor(Class<?>... domainTypes) {
    Collections.addAll(exposeIdsFor, domainTypes);
    return this;
}
```

I want to pass to `exposeIdsFor` all the classes annotated with `@org.springframework.data.mybatis.annotations.Entity` using their package location :

- `packageA`: com.packageA.domain
- `packageB`: com.packageB.domain

It should look like :

```
@Override
public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
    config.exposeIdsFor(...);
}
```

How is it possible?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/259140/1032167  https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections + `new Reflections("my.package").getTypesAnnotatedWith(MyAnnotation‌​.class)`

Comment: @varren I have tried reflection and it does not work during test because of this:  https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections/issues/80 do you have another solution?