# Is it possible to get basePackages value from Spring application context?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I'm working on a Spring extension (implementing some logic in a bean that will be constructed by Spring and provide some useful features to a developer). 
**Is there a way to get basePackages (ComponentScan uses it to find our beans) value from my bean?**

UPD: no, I know how to scan a classpath. I want to know what packages a current instance of Spring ApplicationContext did scanned to find it's beans.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scanning Java annotations at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259140/scanning-java-annotations-at-runtime)

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to get this value at runtime without the help of reflection.

Spring uses `basePackages` that you've specified in the configuration, if you did it, otherwise it uses the package of your entry point class as a `basePackages` value by default.