# Identifying Start-Class during runtime in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am trying to identify a way to know the name of the `Main-Class` that started SpringBoot.
e.g.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SampleApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleApplication.class, args);
    }


@RestController
public class SampleController
{
   @GetMapping("/hello")
   pubic String sayHello()
   {
      System.out.println("Need start class name: "+System.getProperty("sun.java.command"));
      return "hello";
   }

}

}
```

When I run the springboot using `java -jar myappname.jar` ,the System.getProperty("sun.java.command") returns `org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher`

Can anyone advise, how can I get the name of actual run class. I have tried specifying the `start-class` attribute in the manifest.mf. It still gave me `org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher` as the start-class.

Comment: SampleApplication.class.getName()? What concrete problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I need to find the version of the running jar without necessarily looking in to Manifest.MF.  In pure Java sense, I would like to use `Package pack = Package.getPackage(mainClassName); pack.getSpecificationVersion() ` That is why, I need mainClassName that has @SpringBootApplication annotated.

Comment: Why don't you include the version as a property in the application resources? Would be much easier. The spring boot maven/gradle plugins do that for you: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.1.RELEASE/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#integrating-with-actuator-build-info, https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.1.RELEASE/maven-plugin/build-info-mojo.html

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to `@Autowire` in the `ApplicationContext` and then do `context.getBeansWithAnnotation(SpringBootApplication.class).values().toArray()[0].getClass().getName()`, which will [give you the first (and presumably only) bean in the context annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52806226/9705485)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ryan. How do I get this name, if my Bean is not a Spring-Bean but a simple Java class ? Also, part of my code gets executed event before the spring banner is displayed. I do not have context at that time.

Comment: Perhaps we can chat on this - https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185157/room-for-ryan-dawson-and-jay