# Is there a way to get all the location of an Annotation?

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

The only solution I know to get all the classes and examine whether they have a specific annotation.

```
  for (Class clazz : classes){
            clazz.isAnnotationPresent(SomeAnnotation.class);
  }
```

I would like to use something like this:

```
 List<Class> classesUsingAnnotation = SomeApi.getAllTargetTypeForAnnotation(SomeAnnotation.class)
```

Is there any API out there for this?

Comment: Maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259140/scanning-java-annotations-at-runtime#comment21858125_3391773

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for! Vote for closing.