# Can't return all classes marked with specific annotation using spring ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider

Tags: java, spring, reflection, annotations, classpath

I have legacy spring(not boot) application and
I want to get all classes marked with specific annotation. To acchieve it I use following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1415338/2674303

So I've created following class:

```
@Component
public class MyVerifier {

    public void verify() {
        ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider scanner =
                new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(false);

        scanner.addIncludeFilter(new AnnotationTypeFilter(MyAnnotation.class));

        Set<BeanDefinition> set =  scanner.findCandidateComponents("base.pack")

    }
```

In code I have:

```
package base.pack.ololo.qwery;

@MyAnnotation
public class MyClass...
```

---

```
package base.pack.another.packagename;

@MyAnnotation
public class MyOtherClass...
```

But `set` variable is empty set. Why ?

How to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had issue with Annotation Retention policy so annotaion was not available in Runtime

**OLD(broken) version**

```
@Inherited
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE })
public @interface MyAnnotation{
}
```

**NEW(working) version:**

```
@Inherited
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE })
public @interface MyAnnotation{
}
```