# Finding custom annotation in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I have created a library that have the following 2 annotations:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class PushNotificationHandler

@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class PushNotificationDispatcher
```

And this the following class:

```
data class PushNotification(
    val sender: String,
    val body: String
)
```

There is an application that uses the library and have the following class

```
@PushNotificationHandler
class PushHandler {
    @PushNotificationDispatcher
    @Throws(IOException::class)
    fun dispatch(pushNotification: PushNotification) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I want to be able to find from the library all classes that are annotated with the `PushNotificationHandler` annotation and be able to call all methods that are annotated with the `PushNotificationDispatcher` annotation.

**In short i'm trying to mimic Spring's [RestController](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html) and [PostMapping](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PostMapping.html).**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259140/scanning-java-annotations-at-runtime - check this

Comment: I'm researching about this a couple days ago. I guess in this case, once you have an annotation regarding runtime retention, you should implement a kind of processor to deal with the method invoking. I've found this [post](http://hauchee.blogspot.com/2015/10/annotation-processing-during-runtime.html) but I could not implemented or test it. If it work, please let me know if it helped you :)