# find all java classes on classpath whose simple name matches some regex

Tags: java, reflection, classpath

I would like to search the runtime classpath to find all classes with a simple name that matches some regex.

Example:
Say I have Some.jar on my classpath and that jar contains a class called MyCoolClass.class.
I would like some way of finding all classes that contains the word "Cool" like the one above and perhaps several others.

Also, I would like to get either the Class or the fully qualified class name (such that I can call Class.forName).

Comment: Take into account that a running jvm might have more classes loaded than are on the classpath, because it might have dynamically created classes at runtime or it might have loaded them dynamically from a remote location.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this using the [ClassGraph](https://github.com/classgraph/classgraph) library:

```
// List<URL> myClassPath = ... //get classpath. I got mine from the Maven context since I was developing a Mojo
List<String> foundTypes;
  try (ScanResult scanResult = new ClassGraph().enableClassInfo().overrideClasspath(myClassPath).scan()) {
    foundTypes = scanResult.getAllClasses().getNames().stream().filter(e -> e.contains("Cool")).collect(Collectors.toList());
  }

  foundTypes.forEach(e -> System.out.println(e));
```

Outputs the fully qualified class names.

Alternative libraries thay may (or may not) also be able to achieve this:

- [Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections)
- [Scannotations](http://scannotation.sourceforge.net/)
- [Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.html)
  See fx [Scanning Java annotations at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/259140/6095334) although that Q&A is about a different use case.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Reflextions](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections)

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections( "com.my.package", SubTypes.filterResultsBy( s -> true));
Set<Class<?>> subTypes = reflections.get( SubTypes.of( Object.class).asClass());
  subTypes.stream()
     .filter( t -> t.getName().contains( "Cool"))
     .forEach( t -> { 
        log.info( "Class: {}", t.getName());
     });
```